# What does ~~ ("double tilde") do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was checking out an online game physics library today and came across the ~~ operator.  I know a single ~ is a bitwise NOT, would that make ~~ a NOT of a NOT, which would give back the same value, wouldn't it?

Comment: See also [What is the “double tilde” (~~) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5971645/1048572)

Answer (score 288, accepted):

It removes everything after the decimal point because the bitwise operators implicitly convert their operands to signed 32-bit integers. This works whether the operands are (floating-point) numbers or strings, and the result is a number.

In other words, it yields:

```
function(x) {
  if(x < 0) return Math.ceil(x);
  else return Math.floor(x);
}
```

only if *x* is between -(2<sup>31</sup>) and 2<sup>31</sup> - 1. Otherwise, overflow will occur and the number will "wrap around".

This may be considered useful to convert a function's string argument to a number, but both because of the possibility of overflow and that it is incorrect for use with non-integers, I would not use it that way except for "code golf" (*i.e.* pointlessly trimming bytes off the source code of your program at the expense of readability and robustness). I would use `+x` or `Number(x)` instead.

---

#### How this is the NOT of the NOT

The number -43.2, for example is:

> -43.2<sub>10</sub> = 11111111111111111111111111010101<sub>2</sub>

as a signed (two's complement) 32-bit binary number. (JavaScript ignores what is after the decimal point.) Inverting the bits gives:

> NOT -43<sub>10</sub> = 00000000000000000000000000101010<sub>2</sub> = 42<sub>10</sub>

Inverting again gives:

> NOT 42<sub>10</sub> = 11111111111111111111111111010101<sub>2</sub> = -43<sub>10</sub>

This differs from `Math.floor(-43.2)` in that negative numbers are rounded toward zero, not away from it. (The floor function, which would equal -44, always rounds down to the next lower integer, regardless of whether the number is positive or negative.)

Comment: Which is to say, `~~` is a shorthand way (and possibly a good solution?) for creating a [truncate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net), but obviously [in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16696848/1028230).

Comment: JSLint will complain about the use of `~~`.

Comment: Try Math.trunc()

Answer (score 36):

The first ~ operator forces the operand to an integer (possibly after coercing the value to a string or a boolean), then inverts the lowest 31 bits. Officially ECMAScript numbers are all floating-point, but some numbers are implemented as 31-bit integers in the SpiderMonkey engine.

You can use it to turn a 1-element array into an integer. Floating-points are converted according to the C rule, ie. truncation of the fractional part.

The second ~ operator then inverts the bits back, so you know that you will have an integer. This is not the same as coercing a value to boolean in a condition statement, because an empty object {} evaluates to true, whereas ~~{} evaluates to false.

```
js>~~"yes"
0
js>~~3
3
js>~~"yes"
0
js>~~false
0
js>~~""
0
js>~~true
1
js>~~"3"
3
js>~~{}
0
js>~~{a:2}
0
js>~~[2]
2
js>~~[2,3]
0
js>~~{toString: function() {return 4}}
4
js>~~NaN
0
js>~~[4.5]
4
js>~~5.6
5
js>~~-5.6
-5
```

Comment: also `~~undefined // 0`

Comment: also `~~null // 0`

Comment: Technically you have the wrong order. The second `~` does what you described the first `~` does and vice versa. The `~` operator is a unary operators and is interpereted from right to left `~~X` is like `~(~X)` not like `(~~)X` (which would be a syntax error)

Answer (score 25):

In ECMAScript 6, the equivalent of `~~` is [Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc):

> Returns the integral part of a number by removing any fractional digits. It does not round any numbers.

```
Math.trunc(13.37)   // 13
Math.trunc(42.84)   // 42
Math.trunc(0.123)   //  0
Math.trunc(-0.123)  // -0
Math.trunc("-1.123")// -1
Math.trunc(NaN)     // NaN
Math.trunc("foo")   // NaN
Math.trunc()        // NaN
```

The polyfill:

```
function trunc(x) {
    return x < 0 ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x);
}
```

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, ~~ is faster than Math.trunc, http://jsperf.com/math-trunc-vs-double-bitwise-not-operator. Though, not everything is about speed; readability too.

Comment: There is an important difference between ~~ and Math.trunc: if you pass a string, or NaN or whatever thing that's not a number, Math.trunc will return NaN, and ~~  will always return a number, in those cases, it will return 0.

Comment: Math.trunc is marginally faster than ~~ in Chrome 59+, according to http://jsperf.com/math-trunc-vs-double-bitwise-not-operator.

Answer (score 14):

The `~` seems to do `-(N+1)`. So `~2 == -(2 + 1) == -3`. If you do it again on -3, it turns it back: `~-3 == -(-3 + 1) == 2`. It probably just converts a string to a number in a round-about way.

See this thread: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/double-tilde/51608

Also, more detailed info is available here: https://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/28/

Answer (score 11):

Given `~N` is `-(N+1)`, `~~N` is then `-(-(N+1) + 1)`. Which, evidently, leads to a [neat trick](https://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/28/).

Comment: Have to scroll down to Matt's comment to see it in proper use ;)

Answer (score 9):

Just a bit of a warning. The other answers here got me into some trouble.

The intent is to remove anything after the decimal point of a floating point number, but it has some corner cases that make it a bug hazard. I'd recommend avoiding ~~.

First, ~~ doesn't work on very large numbers.

`~~1000000000000 == -727279968`

As an alternative, use `Math.trunc()` (as Gajus mentioned, `Math.trunc()` returns the integer part of a floating point number but is only available in ECMAScript 6 compliant JavaScript). You can always make your own `Math.trunc()` for non-ECMAScript-6 environments by doing this:

```js
if(!Math.trunc){
    Math.trunc = function(value){
        return Math.sign(value) * Math.floor(Math.abs(value));
    }
}
```

I wrote a blog post on this for reference: http://bitlords.blogspot.com/2016/08/the-double-tilde-x-technique-in.html

Answer (score 5):

Converting Strings to Numbers

```
console.log(~~-1);    // -1
console.log(~~0);     // 0
console.log(~~1);     // 1
console.log(~~"-1");  // -1
console.log(~~"0");   // 0
console.log(~~"1");   // 1
console.log(~~true);  // 1
console.log(~~false); // 0
```

~-1 is 0

```
if (~someStr.indexOf("a")) {
  // Found it
} else  {
  // Not Found
}
```

[source](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/)

Answer (score 2):

`~~` can be used as a shorthand for `Math.trunc()`

`~~8.29 // output 8`

`Math.trunc(8.29) // output 8`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how this operator can be used efficiently, where it makes sense to use it:

```
leftOffset = -(~~$('html').css('padding-left').replace('px', '') + ~~$('body').css('margin-left').replace('px', '')),
```

Source:

[See section ***Interacting with points***](http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/examples/)

[above link down - here it is on the wayback machine *(takes a long time to load)*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706183112/http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/examples/)

Answer (score 1):

Tilde(~) has an algorihm -(N+1)

For examle:

```
~0 = -(0+1) = -1
~5 = -(5+1) = -6
~-7 = -(-7+1) = 6
```

Double tilde is -(-(N+1)+1)

For example:

```
~~5 = -(-(5+1)+1) = 5
~~-3 = -(-(-3+1)+1) = -3
```

Triple tilde is -(-(-(N+1)+1)+1)

For example:

```
~~~2 = -(-(-(2+1)+1)+1) = -3
~~~3 = -(-(-(3+1)+1)+1) = -4
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as `Math.abs(Math.trunc(-0.123))` if you want to make sure the `-` is also removed.

Comment: `~~(-1.23)` yields -1, while `Math.abs(Math.trunc(-1.23))` yields 1

Answer (score 0):

In addition to truncating real numbers, `~~` can also be used as an operator for updating counters in an object.  The `~~` applied to an undefined object property will resolve to zero, and will resolve to the same integer if that counter property already exists, which you then increment.

```
let words=["abc", "a", "b", "b", "bc", "a", "b"];
let wordCounts={};    
words.forEach( word => wordCounts[word] = ~~wordCounts[word] + 1 );
console.log("b count == " + wordCounts["b"]);  // 3
```

The following two assignments are equivalent.

```
wordCounts[word] = (wordCounts[word] ? wordCounts[word] : 0) + 1;
wordCounts[word] = ~~wordCounts[word] + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`~~` is two unary **bitwise-not** operators next to one another.

This is used as a shorter and [usually faster](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/11037/0/double-tilde-vs-mathfloor) substitute for `Math.floor()` for **small, positive** numbers. Since it also performs a conversion to number step it can also be used as replacement of `parseInt`, though `~~` will yield 0 when `parseInt` would have given `NaN`, e.g: `~~("a1")` gives `0`, while `parseInt("a1")` gives `NaN`. Also see this [whatever-to-number conversion table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106702/9878263).

For small numbers that can be negative, it is equivalent to `Math.trunc()`: it removes everything to the right of the decimal.

For numbers whose absolute value is bigger than `2 ** 31` (`2_147_483_648`) the bitwise-not "overflows" and applying it twice gives a number whose sign and value are off:

- `~~(2 ** 31)` gives `-2_147_483_648`
- `~~(2 ** 31 + 1)` gives `-2_147_483_647`

To go deeper, the `~` computes the bitwise complement on the 32-bit integral part of a number. Running it twice leaves us with just a 32-bit integral cast. Also see the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-number-bitwiseNOT) and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) of this operator.