# How to get the 'age' from input type 'date' using html & js?

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

My question is how to get the age from the date input type using Javascript, and show it in Html.

I want the user to be able to select his **Date of Birth** from the **Date** input type, which should then be put into the 'bday' ID that I can then use to calculate the age from and fill it in the 'resultBday' element ID.

For example:
When the user selects 'January 15th, 1990' I want it to show "24 years old" in the innerHtml.

This is what I currently have:

HTML:

```
<p id="resultBday"></p>
<input type="date" name="bday" id="bday" onchange="submitBday()">
```

JS:

```
function submitBday () {
    var Q4A = "Your birthday is: "
    var Bday = document.getElementById('bday').value;
    Q4A += Bday;

    var theBday = document.getElementById('resultBday');
    theBday.innerHTML = Q4A;
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Surely it's *How to get the 'age' from input type 'date' using html & js?*? I.e. the title?

Comment: But the code works...

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site

Comment: Is this supposed to be a self answering question maybe?

Comment: @Cristy - the code just shows the selected date, it doesn't calculate the age.

Comment: Oh, so the question actually is "How to get age from birthdate..."

Comment: Javascript Age count from Date of Birth - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786186/javascript-age-count-from-date-of-birth

Comment: who knows, I'm voting to close unless there is some clarification?

Comment: For example, the user selects January 15th 1990, that it will then show "24 years old" in the 'resultBday'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function submitBday() {
    var Q4A = "Your birthday is: ";
    var Bdate = document.getElementById('bday').value;
    var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
    Q4A += Bdate + ". You are " + ~~ ((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
    var theBday = document.getElementById('resultBday');
    theBday.innerHTML = Q4A;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/exVh2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to calculate the Year and month is as below:

HTML:

```
<label>Your Date of Birth <label>
<input type="date" name="birthday" id='birthday' onchange="ageCount()"> 

<p id="demo">age shows here</p>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
  function ageCount() {
    var now =new Date();                            //getting current date
    var currentY= now.getFullYear();                //extracting year from the date
    var currentM= now.getMonth();                   //extracting month from the date
      
    var dobget =document.getElementById("birthday").value; //getting user input
    var dob= new Date(dobget);                             //formatting input as date
    var prevY= dob.getFullYear();                          //extracting year from input date
    var prevM= dob.getMonth();                             //extracting month from input date
      
    var ageY =currentY - prevY;
    var ageM =Math.abs(currentM- prevM);          //converting any negative value to positive
      
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ageY +' years ' + ageM +' months';
    }
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
get ageData(){
      const today = new Date();
      const newDate = new Date(this.dateOfBirth)
      const age = today.getFullYear() - newDate.getFullYear()
      console.log(newDate.getFullYear());
      return age;
    }
    return ageDate
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).