# calculate age without submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I've checked this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21337187/7425712  and it works a great, but I think how I can get age without submit. I just want that

```
<p>You are 29</p>
```

printed and nothing else.

```
function submitBday() {
   var Q4A = "Your birthday is: ";
   var Bdate = document.getElementById('bday').value;
   var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
   Q4A += Bdate + ". You are " + ~~ ((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
   var theBday = document.getElementById('resultBday');
   theBday.innerHTML = Q4A;
}
```

I've tried something like this, but I'm not good with js.

```
 var Bdate = new Date("01/30/1989");
```

thanks! :)

Comment: You need something to trigger the function, submit or not.  Under what condition do you want the calculation to happen?  On click (of something), on change, on focus, etc.

Comment: There's no submit in the other question, it uses `onchange`. What's your question about this?

Comment: try to analyze [this](https://codepen.io/tipsoftheday/pen/hwFde). format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: You shouldnt copy a code if you dont fully understand it