# Given a start date , how to calculate number of years till current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a start date value to be entered in a textbox in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, and as soon as value is entered in it, i want to fire onchange event for that textbox and and use current date to calculate number of years passed.

How can i do this in JavaScript, i have implemented in C#. is there any function in javascript which will help me calculate number of years between two dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i got the solution

[Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant with d/m/yyyy

`d/m/yyy` should be `ISO` compatible i.e : `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
var g="22/12/1978".split('/')

 new Date().getFullYear()- new Date(g[2]+"/"+g[1]+"/"+g[0]).getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date manually and then use getFullYear() to calculate the difference. You can also use a library to parse the date, like jQuery UI

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate