# Get age from Birthdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

In some point of my JS code I have jquery date object which is person's birth date. I want to calculate person's age based on his birth date.

Can anyone give example code on how to achieve this.

Comment: Downvoted, as it is [easily searchable](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=get%20age%20from%20birth%20date%20javascript). Can't think how you got that upvote!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this function...

```
function calculate_age(birth_month,birth_day,birth_year)
{
    today_date = new Date();
    today_year = today_date.getFullYear();
    today_month = today_date.getMonth();
    today_day = today_date.getDate();
    age = today_year - birth_year;

    if ( today_month < (birth_month - 1))
    {
        age--;
    }
    if (((birth_month - 1) == today_month) && (today_day < birth_day))
    {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

OR

```
function getAge(dateString) 
{
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
    {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

[**See Demo.**][1]
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/mkginfo/LXEHp/7/

Comment: Very cool! 
Seeing as how you only have one command in the if (age--;), the brackets are optional, but still pretty good. I'd also combine all the var declarations into one split with commas, but overall, great code, very useful. Thanks mate!

Comment: Tried the demo and gave date of birth as 01 June 1998 (today is 02 Nov 2016). That means the person 18 years old now. But it shows error message that Age should be greater than or equal to 18.
Not accurate thus vote down.

Comment: very helpfull code

Comment: how if the ages are taken from axios json array to be use in v-for?

Answer (score 38):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/xHTPL/)

You can calculate with Dates.

```
var birthdate = new Date("1990/1/1");
var cur = new Date();
var diff = cur-birthdate; // This is the difference in milliseconds
var age = Math.floor(diff/31557600000); // Divide by 1000*60*60*24*365.25
```

Comment: I think you forgot to multiply by 24 in last row

Comment: Hehe *doh*. Nevertheless JsFiddle was right. Thanks

Comment: Probably best to divide by 1000*60*60*24*365.25

Comment: Probably to remove the last ')' small closing bracket. -

Comment: One-liner: ```Math.floor((new Date() - new Date("1990-01-01")) / 31557600000)```

Answer (score 8):

```
function getAge(birthday) {
    var today = new Date();
    var thisYear = 0;
    if (today.getMonth() < birthday.getMonth()) {
        thisYear = 1;
    } else if ((today.getMonth() == birthday.getMonth()) && today.getDate() < birthday.getDate()) {
        thisYear = 1;
    }
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear() - thisYear;
    return age;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fragmentedreality/MfBdg/)

Comment: More accurate than the one above marked AS the answer. Thanks!!

Comment: i think "getDate()" is causing issues in some browsers, i believe.