# Javascript Date string to Age

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

Suppose I have a string of the form `Apr 1928`, and I want to get the age of this person (`84` in this case).  It's okay if I'm one year off in the special case where the current month is that one and it's unclear which day they were born.  What would be the simplest, most elegant way to get the person's age?

Comment: I think it would be subtraction. What did you try, we are not your code mill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008050/get-age-from-birthdate

Comment: Thanks Nile, it should be possible to figure out based on that answer.  Voting to self-close