# error with getTime() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to create a page that has an input option for date of birth. Once the submit button is clicked, I want to verify that the person is not underage (above 18).

This is my HTML code

```
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="#">

  <p>Date of birth: <input type="date" name="dob" value="MM-DD-YYYY" required></p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate_date_of_birth()">
</form>
```

and this is my javascript function:

```
function validate_date_of_birth(){
    var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["dob"].value;
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - dob.getTime();
    return true;
}
```

I'm getting a problem with dob.getTime(). Note that I'm not really verifying the age in the above code. That would require an if loop to verify the age. I'm stuck at a point where the difference is not being calculated.
I tried to check the values of Date.now() and dob.getTime() by using the alert() function in javascript. For dob.getTime(), the value it prints out is "undefined".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008050/get-age-from-birthdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getTime()` is a method of `Date/Time object` in JavaScript.

`var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["dob"].value;` is not a valid `Date` object as this is a string.

which caused you an error in `dob.getTime()`.

to prevent the error simply parse `dob` to Date first after setting it.

```
var dob = new Date(document.forms["myForm"]["dob"].value);
```

OR

```
var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["dob"].value;
dob = new Date(dob);
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You used `getTime()` on the input value, but you need to use it on a `Date` object. For this, construct a `Date` object from the input value, and then you'll be able to get the time on it. Be careful though, `Date` needs to be in one of these formats :

- `YYYY-MM-DD`
- `MM/DD/YYYY`
- Mar 25 2015
- Wednesday March 25 2015

otherwise you'll get an error. You can obviously receive any format and then reformat it to what you need though.

```js
function validate_date_of_birth(){
    var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["dob"].value;
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - new Date(dob).getTime(); // we make a new Date object from dob
    console.log(ageDifMs);
    return false; // so we can see the result and not be redirected
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="">

  <p>Date of birth: <input type="date" name="dob" value="YYYY-MM-DD" required></p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate_date_of_birth()">
</form>
```

[Date reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)