# Angular - Is it possible to calculate the age of someone directly in template?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'm doing `{{today.getTime() - employee?.birthDate.getTime()}}`, today being a Date instance with the date of today and employee?.birthDate being an instance of Date with the birthDate of the employee.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get age from Birthdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008050/get-age-from-birthdate)

Comment: What have you tried, what's wrong with it and can you make a small repro? (stackblitz for ex)

Comment: My bad, I was doing this with a null employee's birthDate, will upload my post tomorrow if I have some issues. The form I tried is `{{today.getTime() - employee?.birthDate.getTime()}}`

Comment: have you tried the [date pipeline](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)?  It has variety of options which you can use

Comment: Yes I think I'll use it with the result of today.getTime() - birthdate.getTime()