# Javascript Date() to calculate age not working by the days

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, as taken from here: [Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

```
        var today = new Date();
        birthday_val = $(".datepicker").val().split('/'); // input value
        birthday = new Date(birthday_val[2],birthday_val[1],birthday_val[0]); // birthday date object
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth();
        var d = today.getDay() - birthday.getDay();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthday.getDate()) ) {
            age--;
        }
```

It calculates it right except for the day - doesnt take this into account and I cant figure out why. Any takers?

Comment: What is going wrong?  Can you give an example?  You are aware that getDay() returns the day of the week (0-6)?

Comment: Can you give an example where it's wrong?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I got the values the wrong way round in : birthday = new Date(birthday_val[2],birthday_val[1],birthday_val[0]); was meant to be birthday = new Date(birthday_val[2],birthday_val[0]-1,birthday_val[1]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** This isn't the correct answer, despite being marked so by the OP.

---

You're using the incorrect method to retrieve the day of the month.

`Date.getDay` returns the day of the week

`Date.getDate` returns the day of the month

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I got the values the wrong way round in : birthday = new Date(birthday_val[2],birthday_val[1],birthday_val[0]); was meant to be birthday = new Date(birthday_val[2],birthday_val[0]-1,birthday_val[1]);

Comment: The answer is wrong though, because you're not even using the value of `d` at all; the root cause was something else altogether.