# javascript date validation check

Tags: javascript, datetime

I will get the date of birth value dynamically from users visiting to the site, but when the user will insert birthday value I have to check whether the user is 18 years old or not.

user will insert a value like `18/09/2012` as `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

```
    var arr   = date.split("/"); //date is the value of birth date.
    var day   = arr[0];
    var month = arr[1];
    var year  = arr[2];
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Wouldn't searching SO with `[javascript] age validation` provide some answers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate age in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following question, it will help you calculate the age -
[Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

```
function getAge(dateString) 
{
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
    {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try any of these functions [Age Calculation from Date of Birth Using Javascript/Jquery](http://pankajlalwani.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/age-calculation-from-date-of-birth-using-javascriptjquery/) or check this one [Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)