# Calculate age depending upon current date & birth Date

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

I have create form which includes Birth date,Current Date,Age text boxes,current date display by default in text box,when choose birth date I want calculate age & display it into age text box..
My Java script code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function aaa()
{
    date= new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m= date.getMonth()+1;
    var y= date.getFullYear();

    document.getElementById('ddd').value=m + '/' + d + '/' + y;
}
function display()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('eee').getDate.value;
    var b = document.getElementById('eee').getMonth.value;
    var c = document.getElementById('eee').getFullYear.value;

    //var aa= document.getElementById('eee').(this).('getDate').value;
    var e= y - c;
    {
      document.write("Ans="+e);
    }
alret(e);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="aaa();">
<form name="xyz" method="post">
    CurrentDate:<input type="text" name="ddd" id="ddd" readonly="readonly"> 
    BirthDate:<input type="date" name="eee" id="eee">
    Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="display();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your question is???