# Fancybox not displaying YouTube video since iOS6

Tags: javascript, youtube, fancybox

This is the code I have been using for the last year. It works great!

```
$("#videos a").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('youtube')) {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'         : $(this).attr('data-width'),
            'height'        : $(this).attr('data-height'),
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                'wmode'     : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
});
```

When this code was used on the iPad the video would display. If the video wasn't viewable on the iPad you would see a YouTube icon with a crossed out play button.

Since iOS6 this has stopped working. Nothing in the code has changed. Instead you now see a white pop up. Has anyone come across this? Does anyone know the cause?

I am using Fancybox 1.3.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make your youtube videos more accessible across different platforms you should stop using the format `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l8MwU0IjMI` (which uses a *swf* player) but use the `embed` method instead (you can get the right code from youtube selecting the `share` tab)

So, instead of this :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l8MwU0IjMI">open youtube video in fancybox</a>
```

... do this :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3l8MwU0IjMI?autoplay=1">open youtube video in fancybox</a>
```

Then modify your fancybox (v1.3.4) script to open the content `type` to `iframe` like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 "width": 620, // or whatever
 "height": 420,
 "type": "iframe"
});
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will give this a go later today.

Comment: This worked for me, just a note that autoplay will not always work depending on the browser (for me it did not work on mobile Safari).  Google documents this here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Autoplay_and_scripted_playback

Comment: @AllInOne : that makes sense, you may not want to waste your data plan with a buffering video.

Comment: @JFK I hear you. But it's good and bad. Now the user has to hit the play button twice.

Comment: @AllInOne : `it's good and bad` is a matter of perspective ;)

Comment: [@martynl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/915230/martynl) : good catch! I corrected the missing function name.

Comment: @AllInOne that has something to do with Apple blocking the use of autoplay, due too mobile network usage.

Comment: @Mattias : as far as I know, mobile doesn't respect autoplay