# Calculate age in years on date select from jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date

I would like to calculate the age of the user as soon as he selects a date from jquery datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#nominee_one_dob" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

    onSelect: function (date) {
        var dob = Date.parse(date);
        if (dob.addYears(18) < Date.today())
        {
            alert("Under 18");
        }
        else
        {
            alert(" Over 18");
        }
    }

  });
```

I am able to get the date selected when i `alert(date)` but I am not getting anything from the further code.

Please help.

Comment: javascript has no `addYears` function

Comment: so how can I get the date of birth?

Comment: there's plenty of similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bugs in your code:**

(1)

```
var dob = Date.parse(date);  //return in milliseconds
```

therefore you can't extract year using `dob.getFullYear()`

(2)

```
Date.today()  //Nope. not available
```

no method available.

**Fixes:**

(1)  `var dob = new Date(date);`

no need to parse, datepicker returns the date not string.

(2)   `var today = new Date();    //returns current dateTime`

(3)  use `.getFullYear()` to extract year from Date.

Remaining code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#nominee_one_dob" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

    onSelect: function (date) {
         var dob = new Date(date);
         var today = new Date();

        if (dob.getFullYear() + 18 < today.getFullYear())
        {
            alert("Under 18");
        }
        else
        {
            alert(" Over 18");
        }
    }

  });
});
```

Working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hNY2c/1/)

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#date_born").datepicker({
  onSelect: calculate,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  maxDate: '+0d',     
  yearRange: '1914:2014',
  buttonImageOnly: false,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});

$("#date_Today").datepicker({
  onSelect: calculate,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  maxDate: '+0d',     
  yearRange: '1914:2014',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});

function calculate() {
  var start = $('#date_born').datepicker('getDate');
  var end       = new Date($('#date_Today').datepicker('getDate'));
  var age_year  = Math.floor((end - start)/31536000000);
  var age_month = Math.floor(((end - start)% 31536000000)/2628000000);
  var age_day   = Math.floor((((end - start)% 31536000000) % 2628000000)/86400000);
  $('#age').val(age_year);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Date <input type="text" name="date_born" id="date_born"/> 
Date Select<input type="text" name="date_Today" id="date_Today"/> 
Age <input type="text" name="age"  id="age" />
```