# form background style not expanding with form in IE8.0

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My css code for the form,

```
form {
            margin:0 auto; 
            text-align:left;
            width:740px;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            padding:15px;
            background:#fff;
            border-radius: 10px; 
            -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
            box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc; 
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc; 
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
            behavior: url(./border-radius.htc);
            font-family:Calibri;
            height: auto;
        }
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/Jzbgj/)

I want the form background to expand with the form, its happening in Chrome but not in IE8.

I have some hidden DIV that are set to visible depending on the selections.

Also how can I get CSS formatting of Chrome and IE look alike.

Ex: if I want to make 2 div visible the form will expand accordingly but the thing is the form border does not extend in IE.

Please check out the entire working code in jsfiddle

[image]

Comment: So what's your problem? Your border remains and content spills out of it? It's no good putting the code in js.fiddle when you problem is with IE8 which is incompatible with jsfiddle.

Comment: @jezzipin yes exactly my content is spilling out of it. I shall remove the code. Thanks for info.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you are trying to use images to achieve the rounded border effect in IE8 that would be acheived using border-radius in other browsers?

Comment: @jezzipin No I am not using images. Its just the border and a bit shadow given to it.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the bad behaviour in IE8. I cannot replicate it with your code.

Comment: @jezzipin screenshot added

Comment: Try adding overflow: hidden; to your form css.

Comment: @jezzipin nope no luck still the same.

Comment: Try my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a container div that goes around your form (in this case called formcontainer) and move the following CSS styles to that class.

```
    .formcontainer{
      border-radius: 10px;  
      -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;  
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        padding:15px;
        width: 740px;
    }
```

Then your form should have the following css rules:

```
        form {
        margin:0 auto; 
        text-align:left;
        width:100%;
        background:#fff;    
        behavior: url(./border-radius.htc);
        font-family:Calibri;
        height: auto;
    }
```

I'm not sure what your behaviour property is doing so you might need to move that to the container div as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jzbgj/1/

**Aside**

Also, your JavaScript may need amending as it displays my age as 25 when I enter my D.O.B when it should be 24.

This may help with your age calculation:
[Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

Comment: behavior is responsible for displaying rounded edges in browsers like IE.

Comment: I'd add that to the container div then although border-radius is what should be used for IE10 now.

Comment: Its done but I am not able to get rounded borders that I used to get using .htc file as you can see in the above screenshot

Comment: What are the contents of the .htc file? With things such as rounded borders you should really look at graceful degradation as IE8 will soon be phased out like IE7.

Comment: border-radius is not supported in IE8 is ther any alternative to it?

Comment: No it's not supported. With graceful degradation you would just use run of the mill squared borders.

Comment: No worries. If this answer has helped, please remember to mark it as correct! I've added a link that might help with the age in my answer.

Comment: Hay thanks for the link and here you go marked the answer as correct