# calculating age in javasctipt using 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following script to calculate age in (years).
This code returns the result as 17 before 12pm and after 12pm it returns as 18.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var dobAge = 03 + "/" + 21 + "/" + 1996;
        dobAge = new Date(dobAge);
        var today = new Date();
        age = Math.floor((today - dobAge) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        alert(age);
    });
```

I want this code to return 18 after 12am itself. 
How is that possible? Please help.

Comment: Tip: don't start numbers with `0`, otherwise they'll be interpreted as octals, not decimals. In your case though it doesn't matter because 3 octal is 3 decimal. If you `use strict` mode it will throw an error.

Comment: The problem is that there are either 365 or 366 days in a year.  There are never 365.25 days in a year.

Comment: So you basically want the "birthday" to occur 12 hours earlier?

Comment: ok i will edit that. But how can I make it 18 yrs after 12am itself?

Comment: Why are you saying "12am itself"? Unless I'm missing something, there's nothing special about 12am.

Comment: @elclanrs—in what version of javascript will '03' in a **date string** be parsed as an octal?

Comment: @paul so what could be the possible solution?

Comment: @sabof no I want the birthday to appear exactly after 12am and not after 12pm

Comment: Fixing the code is a selfish solution.  Suggest fixing planetary orbit instead.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock <- you know 12am is midnight

Comment: I would suggest comparing the months and days first, to figure out if now is before or after the birthdate.  Then look at the difference in years and adjust by 1 if necessary.

Comment: @sabof - I'm not sure I do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7091965/103081

Comment: @adeneo I though 12am was midday

Comment: @RobG: He's using a number, again 03 won't make a difference but try some some other octal, ie http://jsbin.com/fetob/1/edit. Not a realistic example though...

Comment: How about just doing it the right way `new Date(1996, 2, 21)`

Comment: @adeneo It dint make any difference still returning 17 only

Comment: @all I replaced math.floor with math.round and it has rounded off to the nearest decimal. It works fine now. Thanks all!