# Convert birthday to age in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to display age of all my users to grid. I am reading data from facebook.I am not storing it at anywhere.

i am displaying date like :

```
{{ friend.birthday }}
```

How can i display age instead of displaying birthday.

if it is possible to create filters than how to create filter and how to apply it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can implement a function:

Controller:

```
$scope.calculateAge = function calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a date
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

HTML

```
{{ calculateAge(friend.birthday) }}
```

Or a filter:

```
app.filter('ageFilter', function() {
     function calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a date
         var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
         var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
         return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
     }

     return function(birthdate) { 
           return calculateAge(birthdate);
     }; 
});
```

HTML

```
{{ friend.birthday | ageFilter }}
```

Age algorithm taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript).

[EDIT] If the age is less than 1 year, and you want to show months, you can modify the ageFilter to calculate the month difference:

```
app.filter('ageFilter', function() {
     function calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a date
         var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
         var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
         return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
     }
     function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
       if (d1 < d2){
        var months = d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth();
        return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
       }
       return 0;
     }       
     return function(birthdate) { 
           var age = calculateAge(birthdate);
           if (age == 0)
             return monthDiff(birthdate, new Date()) + ' months';
           return age;
     }; 
});
```

[Demo Plunker - Age Function](http://plnkr.co/edit/jniqcrvKvAEiEtfYro6e?p=preview)
[Demo Plunker - Age Filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/sKiPYc0idgq4SuQ4SBRN?p=preview)
[Demo Plunker - Age Filter with Months < 1 year](http://plnkr.co/edit/x06yG4HIhb9pFoEnzPwz?p=preview)

Comment: That works well. Thanks for this solution. However, in cases where a baby's age is less than 1 year, instead of showing Age as '0', how can I modify this so it shows in months like `6 months` for age?

Comment: Updated answer to include baby months < 1 year

Comment: This solution does not work in some cases. It outputs 0 years for birthday 1.1.2015 on 26.01.2016 (day.month.year).

Comment: It does work... month starts at index 0.  So, month 0 is Jan, month 1 is Feb. Did you make the mistake of thinking 1 is Jan?

Comment: Why ```geDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970``` ?

Comment: @pixelbits - Hi, I need your help can we connect?

Comment: How can I help?

Answer (score 4):

If you're value is just for example "05/01/2016". This will be a useful code to convert the date to birthday.

AngularJS

```
app.filter('ageFilter', function(){
    return function(birthday){
        var birthday = new Date(birthday);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = ((today - birthday) / (31557600000));
        var age = Math.floor( age );
        return age;
    }
});
```

HTML

```
{{ relationTypePreDefined.birthdate | ageFilter }}
```

By the way I used this solution to convert a date coming from a jquery datepicker input to age.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using momentjs. Then you can create filter simply by using this snippet

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "04/09/2013 14:20:30";

moment.utc(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

Idk why I can never reply to people, says I need more rep but to rep I need to comment.. whatever.

In response to @Dean Christian Armada's, I kept getting an error regarding the filter. But changing to the following seems to work fine so I do appreciate it!

```
$scope.getAge = function(birthday){
    var birthday = new Date(birthday);
    var today = new Date();
    var age = ((today - birthday) / (31557600000));
    var age = Math.floor( age );
    return age;
  }
```

And for the HMTL

```
{{ getAge(birthdate) }}
```