# angular age validation using date input

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to validating the age(i.e, greater than 18) using the angular directive. can anybody help me the validating the age?

```
<input type="date" data-ng-model="personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.dob"  name="dob" ng-required="true" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : personalDetailForm.dob.$invalid, 'no-errors' : personalDetailForm.dob.$valid}" age-valid="18">
```

### Here is my directive

```
.directive('ageValid', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          ageValid: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
              var todayDate = new Date(),
                  todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear(),
                  todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth(),
                  todayDay = todayDate.getDate(),
                  dateFieldVal = value;
                  console.log(dateFieldVal);
                  var formattedDate = $filter('date')(dateFieldVal,'yyyy-MM-dd');                  
                  console.log(formattedDate);

              /*var isValid = (value.length === $scope.ngLength);
              ngModel.$setValidity($attrs.ngModel, isValid);*/
          });
        } 
    }
  }])
```

Comment: Can you add any fiddle/plnkr?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a directive for that, you can just:

```
<input type="date" max="{{minAge | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"/>
```

And your controller:

```
  var today = new Date();
  var minAge = 18;
  $scope.minAge = new Date(today.getFullYear() - minAge, today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i8dnsSQ277hj6VBrbKZl?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

First of all calculate age may this link help you [calculate age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883308/convert-birthday-to-age-in-angularjs)

and then in input tag use min, max attribute to validate
age.