# Bind to a property which is a formula exposing another

Tags: angularjs

In Angular (1.3), I want to be able to enter a `dob` field of my `person` object and this has another property called `age` which calculates the age based on the `dob`.

So I have the field to enter `dob` as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="player.dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
</div>
```

and I display some of the information that the user types, as they type (name, sex, description etc) but when the user enters the `dob`, I want to automatically display `age` like this:

```
<div>{{player.age}}</div>
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: i think here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883308/convert-birthday-to-age-in-angularjs

Comment: Nice one, I didn't think about using a filter. I don't even need an age property. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but if I'm correct you can create a custom filter to display the age based on the `dob` input, as below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.player = {};
  })

  .filter('ageFilter', function() {
    return function(dob) {
      var ageDifMs = Date.now() - new Date(dob).getTime();
      var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
      return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
    };
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="player.dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-if="player.dob" ng-bind="player.dob | ageFilter"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: slightly different to what I ended up doing but ultimately, a filter was the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngChange

```
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="player.dob" ng-change="calculateAge()" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.calculateAge = function(){
    //do the calculations you want
}
```