# angularjs substract value and remove last four digits

Tags: angularjs

In my application displaying the users age based on their date of birth

controller

```
  $scope.currentIDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyyMMdd');
  $scope.dob = 19840623 # converted user age into yyyyMMdd format
```

view

```
  {{currentIDate - dob}} -- 300297
```

How to remove last 4 digest using filter to get users age?

here is the code :

```js
// Code goes here

function simpleController($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.currentIDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyyMMdd');
  $scope.dob = 19840623
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app=''>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.22" data-semver="1.2.22" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Display Age</h1>
    <div ng-controller='simpleController'>
      Today: {{currentIDate}} <br>
      DOB: {{dob}} <br>
      Sub: {{currentIDate - dob}} <br>
      Age: {{currentIDate - dob | limitTo:2}} <br>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: why don't you filter the date with "yyyy" pattern before, instead of post processing it?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this it will work :

```js
function simpleController($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.currentIDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyyMMdd');
  $scope.dob = 19840623
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app=''>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.22" data-semver="1.2.22" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Display Age</h1>
    <div ng-controller='simpleController'>
      Today: {{currentIDate}} <br>
      DOB: {{dob}} <br>
      Sub: {{currentIDate - dob}} <br>
      Age: {{((currentIDate - dob)/10000) | number:0 }} <br>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```