# Difference in Years Months after a field is changed and update a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form that contains a date field and a other empty div:

```
<input type="date" name="b_day" id="b_day" />
<div id="age"></div>
```

I want after a visitor fills the field the div `age` to look something like "`10.5 yo`" calculating the difference in years-months from today, without refreshing the page

Comment: You can do this direct in javascript or (if you really want to send the information to PHP) send this info with AJAX. Did you tried something like this? I think that your question is too broad.

Comment: Ajax will work better for me but what would be the proper syntax to call the php script that I have ready and works fine

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. do more research.

Comment: @Yogesh, In order for me to ask a question means that I already done my research and if I was a super developer I wound  need any help. Thanks for the recommendation... I will do so. In the mean time your knowledge is what I need

Comment: If you've done your research, what did you try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate age in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript, making use of its [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object. I'd probably end up with something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="b_day" id="b_day" onchange="calculateAge()" />
<div id="age"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function calculateAge() {
  var b_day = new Date(document.getElementById('b_day').value);
  var today = new Date();
  var age = (today.getFullYear() - b_day.getFullYear()) + (((today.getMonth() + 1) - (b_day.getMonth() + 1)) / 12);

  document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = age;
}
```

Note that in JavaScript's Date the months go from 0 to 11, hence the addition of one.