# Calculating age in Javascript with YYYY-mm-dd format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have birthday in following format:

```
1982-09-20
```

I need to get the exact age of the person from that birthdate ( compared with the current date).

What's the easiest way to do this in JS? Can someone help me out please?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the exact age in years.  If you want another value, it's all in that magic number of have in the function below, a bit verbose for clarity:

```
var MILLISECONDS_IN_A_YEAR = 1000*60*60*24*365;
function get_age(time){
    var date_array = time.split('-')
    var years_elapsed = (new Date() - new Date(date_array[0],date_array[1],date_array[2]))/(MILLISECONDS_IN_A_YEAR);
    return years_elapsed; }
```

You would call:
get_age ('1982-09-20')

This is probably going to be marked as a duplicate and deleted. 
There might be a better in built way, but this should work fine for your needs.

Comment: At least you've included a good method for converting a string to a date. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  Simple and works is good.

Comment: "*This is probably going to be marked as a duplicate …*". ;-)