# convert birthday date to age in meanjs

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I want to display age of all users in my meanjs app. 
How can i display age instead of displaying birthdate. my [plunk demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nvo5kMuQImbLk6mvGoD6?p=preview)

**Controller:**

```
$scope.agedate = new Date();
   $scope.calculateAge = function calculateAge(birthday) { 
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

**Html:**

```
<p ng-bind="items.user.displayName"></p>
<p ng-bind="items.user.dateofbirth | date"></p>
<p ng-bind="calculateAge(items.user.dateofbirth)"></p>
```

**my data:-**

```
$scope.items = {
"_id": "5733163d4fc4b31d0ff2cb07",
"user": {
"_id": "5732f3954fc4b31d0ff2cb05",
"displayName": "karthi keyan",
"dateofbirth": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ed948b7bcd1dea2d7086a92d27367170"
},
"__v": 0,
"comments": [],
"content": "this is testing purpose for e21designs",
"categoryone": "Moral Ethics",
"category": "Anonymous Question",
"title": "Worried",
"created": "2016-05-11T11:23:41.500Z",
"isCurrentUserOwner": true
};
```

My [plunk demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nvo5kMuQImbLk6mvGoD6?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost does what you want.

It has a problem in `dateofbirth` property, because it's a string (according your example.

To display it as the date you're using `date` filter which handles this for you.

But, in your `calculateAge` function you need to convert your string into `Date`.

Try the following:

```
$scope.calculateAge = function calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a string
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - new Date(birthday).getTime(); // parse string to date
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this problem is completely unrelated to angularjs. It is pure Javascript date differences calculation.
I strongly suggest to use a third party library like (momentjs)[http://momentjs.com/] to make such calculation, and in order to help you parse the string formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function in javascript to calculate age for the date format "YYYY-MM-DD". Where the **dateString** parameter to the function is the birth date.

```
function calculateAge(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
      age--;
  }
  return age;
}
```

You could use this as an angular function by applying $scope to it. Like this:

```
$scope.calculateAge = function(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
      age--;
  }
  return age;
}
```