# How to determine if the user is 18 years old and up using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to determine if the user is 18 years old and up using jquery. 
Can anyone give me a sample code. I am using datepicker.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `java` is not `javascript`

Comment: Get the date from the datepicker, check if it's 18 years ago.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript) will help you to find age given a `Date` object.

Comment: Have you referred to a tutorial? I suggest you do that for datepicker before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Jquery:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
onSelect: function(value, ui) {
    var today = new Date(), 
        age = today.getFullYear() - ui.selectedYear;
    if(age >= 18)
        $('#age').text("User is 18 years old");
    else
        $('#age').text("User is 18 not years old");
},
maxDate: '+0d',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: '-110:-30'
```

});

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
<div id="age" />
```

Comment: What if they turn 18 later that year? This would say they are 18 when they were actually 17.

Comment: @kirangadhvi but he told to use datepicker

Comment: @kirangadhvi That has the same problem. It assumes they've had their birthday already this year.

Comment: @4castle i am not getting your point friend "What if they turn 18 later that year? "

Comment: Say I was born December 31st, 2000. If today was January 1st, 2018. It would say I was 18, even though I'm actually 17, but I'll turn 18 later that year.