# I'm trying to make a function that outputs age by entering birthdate. I'm not getting an output from this. What I'm I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that calculates age by someone inputting their birth date information. The function does not seem to work when activating the function.

```
function calculate() {    
    var mymonth = 12    //inputs
    var myday =  01     
    var myyear = 1967    
    var month = new Date().getMonth(); // current dates
    var day = new Date().getDate();
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();

    if (month > mymonth) {
            year - myyear;
            return;

    } else if (month > mymonth) {
            year - myyear;
            return;

    } else if (month == mymonth && day == myday){
            year - myyear;
            return;
    } else { 
            year - myyear - 1;
            return;    
    }
}    
calculate();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something like `return year - myyear;`

Comment: I originally had it as "return year - myyear;" but it didn't work either.