# Difference in dates having different formats in html

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a textfield which takes date of birth as input from user. In another textfield i want to set the age calculated. However, the current date and date of birth are in different formats.

Current Date 
   

     Date of birth 
       
    
     Age

The javascript function is as follows:

```
function todayDate(){

       var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("date").value = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
       }

function ageCalculation(){

       var currentDate = new Date();
    var birthDate = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    alert(birthDate);
    var difference = currentDate - birthDate;
    document.getElementById("age").value = difference ;
       }
```

In textfield of age I am getting "NaN"

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21984136/2815635

Comment: What format is dob in?

Comment: That's great. So what's the question?

Comment: dob is in yyy-mm-dd format

Comment: I have updated the question . The difference is NaN

Comment: `object` type minus `string` type, according to ECMA-262 spec it gives you `NaN`. No problem here.

Comment: So what should I change now?

Comment: @Matt Cowley Sry the dob format is mm-dd-yyy

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript Date constructor and `Date.parse` function are capable of bringing various date formats into a single representation in order to make date calculations and other operations with `Date` objects.

Try this:

```
function ageCalculation(){
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dob").value);
    alert(birthDate);
    var difference = currentDate - birthDate;
    document.getElementById("age").value = difference + ' ms';
}
```

To calculate in years:

```
var differenceInYears = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
```

Please, have in mind that this conversion to years is not a precise one due to poor leap year handling. For better precision you might want to implement a better leap year handling algorithm. The best one is mentioned by [Rishi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2815635/rishi) in [the first comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167623/difference-in-dates-having-different-formats-in-html/39167926#comment65677571_39167623).

Comment: Hey it works! But i want age to be calculated in years