# Convert date difference to years to calculate age in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, date-arithmetic

I am using following to calculate age in timestamp difference.

```json
db.getCollection('person').aggregate( [
  { $project: { 
    item: 1, 
    DOB: "$personal.DOB",
    dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$personal.DOB" ] }
  } } 
] )
```

I get the numeric value in `dateDifference`. I want to convert it to years by dividing it with (365*24*60*60*1000). But I don't know how to specify this formula in above query. I have tried the following, but it does not return any value

```json
db.getCollection('person').aggregate( [ 
  { $project: { 
    item: 1, 
    DOB:"$personal.DOB", 
    dateDifference: ({ $subtract: [ new Date(), "$personal.DOB" ] })/(365*24*60*60*1000)
   } } 
] )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**: This answer was for pre Mongo 5.0. Refer to other answers for latest mongo version.

We can just combine the aggregation operators. Note that this solution won't give accurate result as it does not consider leap years

```
db.getCollection('person').aggregate( [ { 
    $project: { 
        date:"$demographics.DOB", 
        age: { 
            $divide: [{$subtract: [ new Date(), "$Demographics.DOB" ] }, 
                    (365 * 24*60*60*1000)]
        } 
     } 
} ] )
```

---

Old solution with `$let`

---

I was able to solve the issue with `$let` expression

```
db.getCollection('person').aggregate( [ { 
    $project: { 
        item: 1, 
        date:"$demographics.DOB", 
        age: { 
            $let:{
                vars:{
                    diff: { 
                        $subtract: [ new Date(), "$demographics.DOB" ] 
                    }
                },
                in: {
                    $divide: ["$$diff", (365 * 24*60*60*1000)]
                }
            }
        } 
     } 
} ] )
```

Comment: But what about leap years? :)

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Any suggestion?

Comment: To do it right you could use one of the approaches from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is incorrect by as many days as there are a leap years that passed since the person was born.  Here's a more correct way to calculate age:

```
{$subtract:[
   {$subtract:[{$year:"$$NOW"},{$year:"$dateOfBirth"}]},
   {$cond:[
      {$gt:[0, {$subtract:[{$dayOfYear:"$$NOW"},
      {$dayOfYear:"$dateOfBirth"}]}]},
      1,
      0
   ]}
]}
```

Comment: could you please explain this further? the last integers 1 and 0, why are they there?

Comment: Your age depends on whether or not we’ve passed your birthday in the current year.

Answer (score 6):

Starting in `Mongo 5.0`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateDiff) aggregation operator:

```
// { "dob" : ISODate("1990-03-27") }
// { "dob" : ISODate("2008-08-07") }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields:
    { age: { $dateDiff: { startDate: "$dob", endDate: "$$NOW", unit: "year" } } }
  }
])
// { "dob" : ISODate("1990-03-27"), "age" : 31 }
// { "dob" : ISODate("2008-08-07"), "age" : 13 }
```

---

This nicely fits the age scenario since (quoting the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/#no-fractional-units)) durations produced by `$dateDiff` are measured by counting the number of times a unit boundary is passed. For example, two dates that are 18 months apart would return 1 year difference instead of 1.5 years.

Also note that [`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) is a variable that returns the current datetime value.

Comment: I am getting the following error with MongoDB 5.0.15:
InvalidPipelineOperator Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$dateDiff'

Comment: Hard to explain, the documentation says it's available as of version 5.0, but maybe your minor version's still too early. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateDiff

Comment: For me the documentation is a bit misleading. The difference between 2012-03-01 and 2013-09-01 is 18 months and is calculated as 1 year. The difference between 2012-09-01 and 2014-03-01 is the same 18 months, but is counted as 2 years because the period includes two new years (New Year's Eve).
So for me this `$dateDiff` is not useful to calculate a person's age.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022**: If the mongo version < 5. This query filters user whose ages are above 65+. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SBDEGdPXu1r)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                diff: {
                  $subtract: [
                    new Date(),
                    {
                      "$toDate": "$birthday"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              in: {
                $divide: [
                  "$$diff",
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      365,
                      24,
                      60,
                      60,
                      1000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          65
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```