# How do I calculate age from birth date in Angular 2 using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 textboxes. One textbox will accept birth date from the user and based on birth date I want to calculate and display their age in another textbox.

Here's my component class

**Student.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col m2">
    <input type="date" id="txtdate">
</div>
<div class="input-field col m4">
    <input type="number" id="age">
</div>
```

**student.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
 selector: 'stud',
 templateUrl: './student.component.html'
 })
 export class StudentComponent implements OnInit
{

     constructor() { }

     ngOnInit() { }

}
function CalculateAge()
{
     var birthdate = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById( "txtdate" );
     var dt = new Date();
     var today = dt.getDate();

}
```

How do I calculate age from birth date?

Comment: try using valueOf: var difference = today.valueOf() - birthdate.valueOf();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Comment: Most answers to this question are incorrect. All answers not using momentjs are incorrect, each has a bug. Proper way in 2022 is using dayjs (30x less bundle size than moment), or use a duplicate link above. Let's close this question, to prevent more incorrect answer spam.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is slight mistake in above code at two places and the fixes are below.
We need to use  `.getTime()` function to get  milliseconds of birthday and 365.25 to round up 29 Feb thing as in the following:

```
let timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.birthdate.getTime());
let age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24))/365.25);
console.log(age)
```

After these two changes it will give you correct age  right up till  364th day of the year.

Comment: You should edit your post to take advantage of the code formating which will makes your post prettier.

Comment: This code has a bug - if you have 2 dates exactly 10 years apart, age should be 10, but your code will give 9.

Answer (score 6):

It could be done using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/):

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

public calculateAge(birthdate: any): number {
  return moment().diff(birthdate, 'years');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col m2">
        <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="birthdate" id="txtdate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m4">
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="age" id="age">
    </div>
    <button (click)="CalculateAge()">Calculate Age</button>
</div>
```

And in your component

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component( {
 selector: 'stud',
 templateUrl: './student.component.html'
 })
 export class StudentComponent implements OnInit
{
    public birthdate: Date;
    public age: number;

     constructor() { }

     ngOnInit() { }

     public CalculateAge(): void
     {
         if(this.birthdate){
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.birthdate);
            //Used Math.floor instead of Math.ceil
            //so 26 years and 140 days would be considered as 26, not 27.
            this.age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24))/365);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not working. After clicking on calculate button i am getting error on console "birthdate.getTime is not a function ".  Please suggest alternative

Comment: I am still facing some issues  at  this line "var timeDiff = Math.abs( Date.now() - this.birthdate );"   its showing me error at this.birthdate   error : "The right hand side of arithmetic operator must be of type any or number"

Comment: I don't see any issues with this part of the code, see `https://plnkr.co/edit/nwUtcjthyshpjOmxmPdz` here for age calculation. Make sure you have defined the birthday above as I have shown above

Comment: The exact same code from above gives me continuously this error:
"The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type." pointing to this.birthdate
Angular 4.2.4 - is this a bug in angular? Did they change anything important there?

Comment: This finally helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622299/date-difference-in-hours-angular-2

let diffInMs: number = Date.parse(date2) - Date.parse(date1);

Comment: I would change two things: 
1. 365 to 365.25, since today is the Feb. 28th 2018 and Mar. 6th returns 26 even though its incorrect
2. to avoid "The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type." error: this.birthdate.getTime()

Answer (score 2):

Age Calculate as year, month,days

```
if (dobDate!=undefined) { 
  var todayDate=new Date();
  var ageyear = todayDate.getFullYear() - dobDate.getFullYear();
  var agemonth = todayDate.getMonth() - dobDate.getMonth();
  var ageday = todayDate.getDate() - dobDate.getDate();

  if (agemonth <= 0) {
    ageyear--;
    agemonth = (12 + agemonth);
  }
  if (nowDay < dobDay) {
    agemonth--;
    ageday = 30 + ageday;
  }  if (agemonth == 12) {
    ageyear = ageyear + 1;
    agemonth = 0;
  }

  alert("Age in Year:" + ageyear + ',' + 'Month:' + agemonth + ',' + 'Day:' + ageday);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if dates are 1 day short of being full 10 years old, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
if (this.dob) {
  //convert date again to type Date
  const bdate = new Date(this.dob);
  const timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - bdate.getTime() );
  this.age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work.

```
calculateAge(dob) {
    if (!dob || dob == "") return "";
    let mdob = moment(dob, "YYYY-MM-DD");
    let age = moment().diff(mdob, "months");
    let yrs = (age / 12).toFixed(1);
    let mnths = age % 12;
    return `${parseInt(yrs)}Y`;
}
```