# Date difference in hours - Angular 2

Tags: date, angular, typescript

How can I get difference in hours between two dates in angular2? I don't want to use external libs like `moment.js`.

Having, for example: *incidentTime = '2017-03-05 11:26:16 AM'* and *creationTime = '2017-03-06 12:26:16 AM'*

```ts
let time = +params.data.incidentTime - +params.data.creationTime;  
console.log("time: " + time);
```

It should return 25 hours, but It returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
const date1 = params.data.incidentTime;
const date2 = params.data.creationTime;

const diffInMs = Date.parse(date2) - Date.parse(date1);
const diffInHours = diffInMs / 1000 / 60 / 60;

console.log(diffInHours);
```

Use `Math.floor` to round the result down, or `Math.ceil` to round it up

Comment: Argument of type '() => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. error on this line let diffInMs = Date.parse(date2) - Date.parse(date1);

Answer (score 2):

parse the date type parameters to javascript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) type.

```
let date1 = new Date(params.data.incidentTime).getTime();
let date2 = new Date(params.data.creationTime).getTime();
let time = date1 - date2;  //msec
let hoursDiff = time / (3600 * 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
let time:any = new Date("2017-03-05 11:26:16").getHours();
let date2:any = new Date("2017-03-06 12:26:16").getHours();
console.log(time -date2, time, date2, "sdfsd");
```

> but It returns NaN

this is because you are using `+` sign before date which is converting youtr date into number format so returning NAN(not a number)

Comment: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type. error on the line #3

Comment: please check the Update @user630209

Comment: what if there are two different dates?

Comment: Example having different dates i guess