# To get the date hour difference between two dates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Refferred [Date difference in hours - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622299/date-difference-in-hours-angular-2), which was not returns

```
let creationDate =params.data.createdTime;
let incidentDate= params.data.incidentTime;
let diffInMs = Date.parse(creationDate) - Date.parse(incidentDate);
let diffInHours = diffInMs / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

Which return wrong anwers or in most case NaN,

```
Date is in this format - `08/03/2017 10:52:58 AM - 06/03/2017 10:48:15 PM`
```

DATEFORMAT : dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a

Comment: You sure you're subtracting the latest date from the earliest date to ensure that you're getting a positive number?  Also, can you be sure that the values you're getting can be parsed unambiguously (like ISO 8601)?

Comment: You sure you're subtracting the latest date from the earliest date to ensure that you're getting a positive number?  - yes made sure this. 2) I didnt get this point Also, can you be sure that the values you're getting can be parsed unambiguously (like ISO 8601)?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to angular js at all. Check moment.js library

Comment: Can't we achieve this with out using external plugin

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer That is just on date, its of date time stamp