# How to calculate difference between to time in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I got the In-time: `11:08:43` and Out-time: `10:21:06` in this format I want to calculate difference between this two time. Type of both time is string. How is it possible in Angular 2?

```
for (let item of this.list) {
    if (item.pin.length == 2) {
        var inTime = item.pin[0].time;
        var outTime = item.pin[1].time;
        let diffInMs: number = Date.parse(outTime) - Date.parse(inTime);
        let diffInHours: number = diffInMs / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        console.log(diffInHours);
    }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript (your question really isn't related to Angular)

Comment: Why your code isn't working ? What is the current output for your example ?  What is your expected output for your example ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (item.pin.length == 2) {
      var inTime = item.pin[0].time;
      var outTime = item.pin[1].time;

      let IN = new Date(` ${item.date} ${inTime}`);
      let OUT = new Date(` ${item.date} ${outTime}`);
      let diff = OUT.getTime() - IN.getTime();
      var msec = diff;
      var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
      msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
      var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
      msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
      var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
      msec -= ss * 1000;
      this.totalHour.push(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a duplicat question of this: [Date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622299/date-difference-in-hours-angular-2)

For user630209 the right answer was

```
let date1: string = params.data.incidentTime;
let date2: string = params.data.creationTime;

let diffInMs: number = Date.parse(date2) - Date.parse(date1);
let diffInHours: number = diffInMs / 1000 / 60 / 60;

console.log(diffInHours);
```

Use Math.floor to round the result down, or Math.ceil to round it up

Comment: Can you add some code ? It's easier if we can see what you have done and understand

Answer (score 0):

```js
getDataDiff(startDate, endDate) { 
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var days = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
    var hours = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60 * 1000)) - (days * 24);
    var minutes = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 1000)) - ((days * 24 * 60) + (hours * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000) - ((days * 24 * 60 * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60));
    console.log(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```