# How to get age from DOB in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to get age from dob efficiently? Will you give me more information?

```js
function myFunction(){
   var d = new Date();
   var year = new Date(document.getElementById('dob').value);   
   var age = d.getFullYear() - year.getFullYear();
   document.getElementById('age').value = age;    
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="dob" placeholder="Date of birthday" onchange="myFunction()"><br/>
   <input type="text" id="age">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Moment.js [https://momentjs.com/] lib for all calculation of time and date

Have fun