# How to get age from date string using angular 2

Tags: javascript

I have to check the age validation, so I have tried the following method for getting age:

```
let newDate = new Date(this.userDob);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - newDate);
let age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
```

here **this.userDob** is a string. How can I use this string to get age using javascript?

Comment: I don't think this question relates to angular, just to javascript data manipulation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

Comment: @RadicalFanatic i have to use angular2. im using angular 2 for my app

Comment: @RahulBridge - in the code you posted, you're not using the angular framework. `new Date(...)` and `Math.abs(...)` and `Math.floor(...)` are pure javascript functions that don't require the angular library.

Comment: @RadicalFanatic how can i use this or how to get age from date ?

Comment: What is the format of the string `this.userDob`?

Comment: @RahulBridge - Have you looked at the question that borkovski commented? It is also talking about calculating an age from a birth date string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it using like this,

```
var dob = //Here Im getting dob
var today = new Date();
var birthDate = new Date(dob);
var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
}
```

Now I'm able to check the age