# display correct age depending on date value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which have a tbody and x number of rows containing persons and their ages like this..

```
                <tbody>

                  <tr>
                    <td class="number">4</td>
                    <td class="name">Name</td>
                    <td class="age" data-date="2004-11-22 00:00:00">13</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="number">5</td>
                    <td class="name">Name</td>
                    <td class="age" data-date="2003-11-22 00:00:00">14</td>
                  </tr>
```

I would like to display the correct age of all persons, but since this depends on the current date I'm thinking of entering the birthdate instead. But I still want to display the actual age of the player. How can I use a jQuery script that iterate all rows of the table and depending on the data-date value display the actual age in the corresponding td cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.age').each(function(i, e) {
  var now = new Date();
  var date = new Date(e.dataset.date);
  $(this).html(now.getFullYear() - date.getFullYear());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="number">4</td>
      <td class="name">Name</td>
      <td class="age" data-date="2004-11-22 00:00:00"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number">5</td>
      <td class="name">Name</td>
      <td class="age" data-date="2003-11-22 00:00:00"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}

$('.age').each(function(index){
    $(this).html(getAge($(this).data('date')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="number">4</td>
      <td class="name">Name</td>
      <td class="age" data-date="2004-11-22 00:00:00">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number">5</td>
      <td class="name">Name</td>
      <td class="age" data-date="2003-11-22 00:00:00">14</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the getAge() function is stolen from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091965/2008111 so maybe you follow that link  and upvote also the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML page should be like this:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <table class="persons">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="number">4</td>
            <td class="name">Name</td>
            <td class="age" data-date="2004-11-22 00:00:00"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="number">5</td>
            <td class="name">Name</td>
            <td class="age" data-date="2003-11-22 00:00:00"></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

The js side should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.persons td.age').each(fucntion(){
      var today = new Date();
      var birthday = new Date($(this).attr('data-date'));
      var ageDifMs = today - birthday.getTime();
      var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
      $(this).html(Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970));    
   });
});
```