# How to restrict user below 18 years to not register using reactjs datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I have successfully implemented the react js datepicker.
Now I want to restrict users below 18 years to not register.

This is my datepicker

```
<DatePicker
 selected={this.state.dob}
 onChange={this.dateChange}
 className="form-control"
 maxDate={new Date()}
 />
```

Suggest me what to do.
Thank You!

Comment: You can't restrict user. Users lie!

Comment: Do you want to restrict it within the datepicker? Otherwise you can check it when user clicks to register.

Comment: How do I do that @AliAnkarali

Comment: The answer in this question has the function to calculate age:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd

You can pass this.state.dob to that function on onSubmit of the form or onClick of the button and continue accordingly.

Comment: In your change handler function do math to see if they're older or younger than 18. Hold a boolean in `this.state` that you set to control the `disabled` prop in the submission button. It'd also be helpful to show an error somewhere, which can controlled with the exact same variable

Answer (score 0):

I have just added "this" to work in desired scope.
Modified code:

```
const ageRestriction = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-18)
<DatePicker
selected = { this.state.dob }
onChange = { this.dateChange }
className = "form-control"
maxDate = { ageRestriction }
/>
```