# calculating amount of months from today's date and a given date

Tags: javascript, date, time

typescript / javascript

I Received a date like this "1500074035"

I Want to be able to know , how much months have been passed from todays , since this date.

```
function diff_months(dt2, dt1) 
 {

  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
   diff /= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));

 }

dt1 = new Date(2014,10,2);
dt2 = new Date(2014,10,11);
console.log(diff_months(dt1, dt2));

dt1 = new Date("June 13, 2014 08:11:00");
dt2 = new Date("October 19, 2014 11:13:00");
console.log(diff_months(dt1, dt2));


but this is wrong .. when the years are different .

i think my problem is here 

   diff /= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4);
```

Comment: what do you already try ? show us some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Comment: function diff_months(dt2, dt1) 
 {

  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
   diff /= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
  
 }

dt1 = new Date(2014,10,2);
dt2 = new Date(2014,10,11);
console.log(diff_months(dt1, dt2));

dt1 = new Date("June 13, 2014 08:11:00");
dt2 = new Date("October 19, 2014 11:13:00");
console.log(diff_months(dt1, dt2));


but this is wrong .. when the years are different .

i think my problem is here 

   diff /= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4);