# How to calculate current age by retrieving data from user's input in my form?

Tags: javascript, html

My form page (HTML) needs user's DOB. And the format is: dd-mm-yyyy and the data type is in text. e.g. April 21st, 1990 is 21-04-1990. My assignment requires that user has to be older than 18 but cannot older be than 80.

My Javascript needs to read user's input and calculate current date minus user's input to check if age qualifies.

I expect the output of DOB to allow or restrict the form's page.

Age = Current Date - User's DOB
If 18 or older go to the next page, deny if less than 18.
If 80 or older, cannot advance to next page.

Comment: You're asking two questions in one: how to [*parse a date formatted as dd-mm-yyyy*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+parse+dd-mm-yyyy) and [*how to calculate age from a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+calculate+age). Both have been answered many times before. What have you tried? Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding changing the format of the date [please read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format/31162426#31162426)

```js
   function get_age(born, now) {
      var birthday = new Date(now.getFullYear(), born.getMonth(), born.getDate());
      if (now >= birthday) 
        return now.getFullYear() - born.getFullYear();
      else
        return now.getFullYear() - born.getFullYear() - 1;
    }

document.getElementById("dateInput").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var input = this.value;
    var dateEntered = new Date(input);
    
       var now = new Date();
        var birthdate = input.split("-");
        var born = new Date(birthdate[0], birthdate[1]-1, birthdate[2]);
        age=get_age(born,now);
     
        console.log(birthdate[2]+" : "+birthdate[1]+" : "+birthdate[0]);
        console.log(age);
    
        if (age<=18)
        {
       alert("Input Error - Age should be greater then or equal to 18");
            return false;
        }
});
```

```html
Birthday: <input type="date" id="dateInput" name="bday">
```

also [read for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Answer (score 0):

```js
   function get_age(born, now) {
      var birthday = new Date(born.getFullYear(), born.getMonth(), born.getDate());
      if (now >= birthday) 
        return now.getFullYear() - born.getFullYear();
      else
        return now.getFullYear() - born.getFullYear() - 1;
    }

document.getElementById("dateInput").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var input = this.value;
    var dateEntered = new Date(input);
    
       var now = new Date();
        var birthdate = input.split("-");
        var born = new Date(birthdate[0], birthdate[1]-1, birthdate[2]);
        age=get_age(born,now);
     
        console.log(birthdate[2]+" : "+birthdate[1]+" : "+birthdate[0]);
        console.log(age);
    
        if (age<=18)
        {
       alert("Input Error - Age should be greater then or equal to 18");
            return false;
        }
});
```

```html
Birthday: <input type="date" id="dateInput" name="bday">
```

Comment: var birthday = new Date(born.getFullYear(), born.getMonth(), born.getDate());

its should be born.getFullYear()

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("dob").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
//FIRST FETCH THE VALUE AND SPLIT IT INTO DATE FORMAT VIA SPLITTING
    var dobInput = this.getValue();
    var birthdate = dobInput.split("-");
        var userBornDate = new Date(birthdate[0], birthdate[1]-1, birthdate[2]);
  //WE CALCULATE THE AGE VIA FULL YEAR
  var age = currentDate.getFullYear() - userBornDate.getFullYear();
         if (age >= 18 && age <= 80) {
    alert("You are eligible to proceed.");
  } else if (age < 18) {
  
    alert("You must be 18 years or older to proceed.");
  } else {
    // Deny access if the user is older than 80
    alert("You cannot proceed as you are older than 80 years.");
  }
});

Birthday <input type ="date" id 'dob' name ='dateofbirth'>
```