# How to calculate age based on date of birth

Tags: jquery

How can I show years and month?

I need to calculate age based on the selected date of birth from the date picker.

But when selecting some date incorrect age displayed.

I have used jquery to calculate to find the age. Sometimes the age is not correct.

I need to show x years and x month old.

When I selecting date like 22-07-2012 show 6 years old.

The actual result is `"7 years old"`

```
 dob = new Date($("#DateOfBirth").val())
 var today = new Date();
 var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
 $('#txtAge').val(age + ' years old');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Comment: Removed the irrelevant tag `C#`, ensure proper usage of tagging

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
dob = new Date($("#DateOfBirth").val())

var dobYear = dob.getFullYear();
var now = new Date(Date.now()).getFullYear();
var age = now - dobYear;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem can be solved using the below code:

First Store the date in a variable, and separate the day, year and month:

```
var mydate = $("#birth_date").val().toString();
var yearThen = parseInt(mydate.substring(0,4), 10);
var monthThen = parseInt(mydate.substring(5,7), 10);
var dayThen = parseInt(mydate.substring(8,10), 10);
```

then get today's date and the birth-date:

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date(yearThen, monthThen-1, dayThen);
```

After that, all that remains is the calculations:

```
var year_age = Math.floor(differenceInMilisecond / 31536000000);
var day_age = Math.floor((differenceInMilisecond % 31536000000) / 86400000);

var month_age = Math.floor(day_age/30);
day_age = day_age % 30;
if (isNaN(year_age) || isNaN(month_age) || isNaN(day_age)) {
        $("#exact_age").text("Invalid birthday - Please try again!");
    }
    else {
        $("#exact_age").html("You are<br/><span id=\"age\">" + year_age + " years " + 
    month_age + " months " + day_age + " days</span> old");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript date object don't have this format `DD-MM-YYYY`, use this format `YYYY-MM-DD`,
Check below code which gives your expected output.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = $("#DateOfBirth").val();
  var dob = new Date(input);
  var today = new Date();
  var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  $("#txtAge").html(age + ' years old');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <input value="2012-07-22" id="DateOfBirth" type='text' />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Age</button>
  <br/>
  <label id="txtAge"></label>
</div>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.