# Calculate and show age of a person from year, month and day

Tags: javascript

I got this as JSON data from the API and need to calculate the age:

```
{"fullname":"Nikita","email":"test@demo.com","city":"London","mobile":"08888888888","birthday"{"year":1980,"month":7,"day":23}}
```

Currently, I'm showing the date of birth as `{{anon.birthday}}` which results in `1980-7-23`. I would like to show the age instead. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried to get the age? Can you post the sample code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the age from {{age}}

Add this on load

```
this.getAge();
```

Then to calculate

```
getAge() {
    const now = new Date();
    const birthdate = new Date(this.anon.birthday.split('-')[0], this.anon.birthday.split('-')[1], this.anon.birthday.split('-')[2]);
    const timeDiff = now.getTime() - birthdate.getTime();
    this.age = Math.floor( timeDiff / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)  `npm i moment`

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

// Get the date of birth as a moment
const birthDateMoment: moment.Moment = moment(`${yourObject.birthday.day}/${yourObject.birthday.month}/${yourObject.birthday.year}, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Option1: using [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/): Get the duration time between now (moment()) and the birthDate

```
const durationLife = moment.duration(moment().diff(birthDateMoment))
durationLife.years();
```

Option 2: Use [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
moment().diff(birthDateMoment, 'years');
```

Option 3: [time from](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/)

```
birthDateMoment.from(moment());
```