# Leap year checker in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, output, leap-year

I'm trying to put a leap year checker in my Age calculator. It worked for sometime and now it outputs "This is a leap year" every time I select a date. What am I doing wrong?? Thank you!

```js
var year;

function ageCalculator() {
  var userinput = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
  var dob = new Date(userinput);

  if (userinput == null || userinput == '') {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "**Choose a date please!";
    return false;
  } else {
    //calculate month difference from current date in time
    var month_diff = Date.now() - dob.getTime();

    //convert the calculated difference in date format
    var age_dt = new Date(month_diff);

    //extract year from date
    var year = age_dt.getUTCFullYear();
    calYear();
    //now calculate the age of the user
    var age = Math.abs(year - 1970);

    //display the calculated age
    return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      "Age is: " + age + " years. ";
  }
}

function calYear() {
  var yr = year;
  var yr = document.getElementsByName("year");
  if (yr % 400 == 0 || (yr % 100 != 0 && yr % 4 == 0)) {
    window.alert("This is not leap!");
  } else {
    window.alert("This is a leap!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="DOB" />
<button type="button" onclick="ageCalculator()">Calculate</button>
<span id="message"></span><br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Why do you want a leap year checker? In case your visitor is born on the 29th of Feb? [DOB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14838925/295783)

Comment: (Offtopic) PS, try always not to use specificities like `document.getElementById("DOB").value` inside a function that does what it says. Instead pass arguments and be happy knowing you can reuse that function with any other elements in any part of your application. `ageCalculator(inputBirth) { /*calc*/ return outputAge; }`

Comment: (Offtopic) Avoid using variables that end up polluting the global Window scope (`var year`). At some point try to `console.log(window.year)` - that's not good.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("year")` is an **Element** not its value! Also, `Element.value` returns **always** a string - and it's your task as a developer to convert strings (or know typecasting by heart) to an integer or a float as necessary.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and create a [mcve].

Comment: Be careful using `new Date(userinput)` where `userinput` is an **invalid ISO8601** string. You can easily get out false positives.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it is worse: `document.getElementsByName("year");` is a collection

Comment: `Date.now() - dob.getTime()` cannot by any means be what the comment says: *`calculate month difference`* that's absolutely not true.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

- `document.getElementsByName("year")` **is a Collection not an Element value**! Also, Element.value **returns always a string** - and it's your task as a developer to convert strings (or know typecasting by heart) to an integer or a float as necessary.
- Don't put specifics into a function (like i.e: `document.getElementById` etc) make it reusable!
- Avoid using variables that end up polluting the global Window scope (`var year`). At some point try to `console.log(window.year)` and you'll see why.
- Don't call a function `calYear()` *?* if it returns a string. Instead call it properly: `isLeap()` and do what it says! Return a Boolean value.
  Only at the point you use/call that function in your UI - decide there the appropriate string you want to show. Don't limit yourself.
- Be always careful while using `new Date(someUserInput)` where *someUserInput* might be **an invalid [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** string. You can easily get false positives.
- PS: `Date.now() - dob.getTime()` cannot by any means be what your comment says: *"calculate month difference"* that's absolutely not true - Be careful when writing your comments and when naming your functions.

```js
/**
 * @param {integer} year
 * @return {boolean} - True if year is leap year
 */
const isLeap = (year) => (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0;

/**
 * @param {string} DOBString - A valid ISO8601 dateString
 * @return {integer} - Age
 */
const calcAge = (DOBString) => {
  const UTC_DOB = new Date(DOBString);
  if (!DOBString || isNaN(UTC_DOB)) return;
  const UTC_today = new Date();
  const m = UTC_today.getUTCMonth() - UTC_DOB.getUTCMonth(); // Month diff
  let age = UTC_today.getUTCFullYear() - UTC_DOB.getUTCFullYear();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && UTC_today.getUTCDate() < UTC_DOB.getUTCDate())) age--;
  return age;
};

// UI/Page/View specific scripts:

const EL_DOB = document.querySelector("#DOB");
const EL_result = document.querySelector("#result");
const EL_leap = document.querySelector("#leap");
const UI_showAgeResult = () => {
  const age = calcAge(EL_DOB.value);
  const UTC_DOB = new Date(EL_DOB.value);
  const is_leap = isLeap(UTC_DOB.getUTCFullYear());
  EL_result.textContent = age ? age : "Insert a valid date";
  EL_leap.textContent =  is_leap ? "Born on a leap year! so cool" : "";
};

// Do it on input Event
EL_DOB.addEventListener("input", UI_showAgeResult);
// And if needed on page init
UI_showAgeResult();
```

```html
<input id="DOB" type="text" value="2000-02-29"/>
<span id="result"></span><br>
<span id="leap"></span>
```

**Important:**
notice that if user *Date Of Birth* is say "2000-02-29", and say *today*'s date is "2001-02-28" the result age will be arguably-correctly `0`.
Only if date is "2001-03-01"  will result as `1` y of age.

**Kudos:**
Slightly modified [@naveen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091965/383904) answer's code for calculating dates diff → age.

Comment: Great Answer Sir

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at this version

[Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd/14838925#14838925)

To fix YOUR code we need to pass the year to the function and not try to use a non-existing year field

If there was such a field, you could access its value with `document.querySelector("[name=year]").value` since document.getElementsByName is a collection and the value would be `document.getElementsByName("year")[0].value`

So what did I do?

- passed the DOB year to the leap function
- calculated the age from the year of the date difference

I tested with 2000-02-29 and 2001-02-28

NOTE the script ALSO works with 02/29/2016 but not with 29/02/2016 (European format)

```js
var year;

function ageCalculator() {
  var userinput = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
  var dob = new Date(userinput);

  if (isNaN(dob)) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "**Choose a date please!";
    return false;
  } else {

    //extract year from date
    var year = dob.getFullYear();
    console.log(year)
    testLeap(year);

    //calculate difference from current date in milliseconds
    var date_diff = Date.now() - dob.getTime();

    //convert the calculated difference in date format
    var age_dt = new Date(date_diff);

   //now calculate the age of the user
    var age = Math.abs(1970 - age_dt.getFullYear());

    //display the calculated age
    return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      "Age is: " + age + " years. ";
  }
}

function testLeap(yr) {
  const isLeap = (yr % 400 == 0 || (yr % 100 != 0 && yr % 4 == 0)) 
  alert(isLeap ? "This is a leap!" : "This is not a leap!");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="DOB" />
<button type="button" onclick="ageCalculator()">Calculate</button>
<span id="message"></span><br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: this code still outputs "This is a leap!" no matter what date I select on the webpage

Comment: No it does not. Try 2000-02-29 and 2001-02-28

Comment: 29/02/2016 is not a valid date to enter in this script. Then we need to fix the input

Comment: `29/02/2016` is the European format and not supported by JS date. You can try 02/29/2016 to test and we need more code to format DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY for the script to work

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a function to check if the input year is a leap year or not, you can use Date object:

```js
function isLeapYear(year) {
    // year, monthIndex, day
    return new Date(year, 1, 29).getFullYear() === year;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

this is function to check if this year is leap year

```
function isLeapYear(year){
 return (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0;
}
```

```
isLeapYear(2000) //true
isLeapYear(2001) // false
```

EDIT:
so the problem is in document.getElementsByName("year")
i think you should have a HTML named year which is have the year value

```
<input type="number" name="year" />
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("year");` is not a value - that is the main problem here

Comment: I did not comment for you to add my comment to your answer. Also your interpretation of my comment was not useful. Please see my answer for a complete answer

Answer (score -2):

Here's another Method I can make sure it will works

```
function ageCalculator() {
  var userinput = document.getElementById("DOB").value;
  var dob = new Date(userinput);

  if (userinput == null || userinput == '') {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "**Choose a date please!";
    return false;
  } else {
    //calculate month difference from current date in time
    var month_diff = Date.now() - dob.getTime();

    //convert the calculated difference in date format
    var age_dt = new Date(month_diff);

    //extract year from date
    var year = age_dt.getUTCFullYear();
    calYear(year);
    //now calculate the age of the user
    var age = Math.abs(year - 1970);

    //display the calculated age
    return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      "Age is: " + age + " years. ";
  }
}

function calYear(yr) {
  if (yr % 400 == 0 || (yr % 100 != 0 && yr % 4 == 0)) {
    window.alert("This is not leap!");
  } else {
    window.alert("This is a leap!");
  }
}
```

Try updating the callYear if condition assuming
yr> 1000 and yr < 8000

```
function calYear(yr) {
  if ((yr % 4 === 0 && yr % 100 !== 0) || yr % 400 === 0 ) {
    window.alert("This is not leap!");
  } else {
    window.alert("This is a leap!");
  }
}
```

Comment: This also outputs "This is a Leap" on my webpage no matter what date is selected.... i'm not sure why it worked for sometime then stopped. I wanted "This is a leap!" only to appear when a user selected the date 29/02/2016 for example

Comment: try to edit callyear if condition into this
asuming yr > 1000 yr < 8000

(yr % 4 === 0 && yr% 100 !== 0) || yr % 400 === 0;