# Check age using Date object in JS

Tags: javascript, date

I need help with the Date object in JS.
I need a return that checks if the patient is an adult based on the DOB.
I am unsure how to go about using the date object to get a return of age in milliseconds (Date returns milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC). If anyone has an idea, I appreciate it.
<3

```
 let today = Date.now()
 function patient(fname, lname, origin, dob){
    this.fname,
    this.lname,
    this.origin,
    **this.dob,**
    this.age = (today - dob)
    this.isAdult = age > 18)}
```

Comment: You don't want milliseconds, you want the date difference in years, see [*Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can convert your DOB to milliseconds since Epoch time with getTime()

for dob, you can set the input variables to be month, day, and year, make a new Date object, and use getTime() to convert it to milliseconds:

```
 function patient(fname, lname, origin, month, date, year){
    this.fname,
    this.lname,
    this.origin,
    this.dob = new Date(`${month} ${day}, ${year}`).getTime()
    this.age = (Date.now() - dob)/1000/60/60/24/365 
    //convert to seconds/minutes/hours/day/year (ignoring leap years for this examples)
    this.isAdult = age > 18)}
```

[Link to CodePen example](https://codepen.io/isaacyong/pen/dyOrYOp)

Now it's just a matter to convert milliseconds back to year, the example above ignores the leap year, depending on the accuracies you going for you can round it up, or write a function to determine the exact numbers down to decimals

Comment: There are [many questions on calculating age](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+get+age) that have better answers. `new Date(\`${month} ${day}, ${year}\`)` produces an invalid date in Safari.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new Date object and call `getTime()` on it to get the unix timestamp.

```js
date = new Date('2020-01-01')
// Wed Jan 01 2020 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
date.getTime()
// 1577836800000
```

Let's say your definition of an "adult" is that someone has to be at least 18 years old. 18 years is `568036800000` milliseconds (assuming 365.25 days per year). Then, your check function would be as follow:

```js
const ADULT_THRESHOLD_MILLISECONDS = 568036800000;

function checkIsAdult(patientDob) {
  const patientDobUnixTimestamp = new Date(patientDob).getTime();
  const currentTimestamp = Date.now();

  return (currentTimestamp - patientDobUnixTimestamp) > ADULT_THRESHOLD_MILLISECONDS;
}
```

Comment: '2020-01-01' is parsed as UTC whereas the OP likely wants local, so you start with an incorrect time value. 568036800000 represents 1 Jan 1988 (UTC), which is 32 years before 1 Jan 2020, not 18. To test for someone to be at least 18 on that date, the comparison date should be 1 Jan 1998.