# How can I calculate age from date of birth react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, rxjs

I have my registration form. And I am trying to calculate the user's age from their date of birth, I found many versions, but none could be adjusted to my project, could you help me throwing ideas at me please, thank you.
I am attaching my registration form below.
I want to implement, that when the user enters his date of birth, with the input date, it does not show me the age in html, but save it and be able to use it in my database

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { addUser, cleanUsers} from "../actions/index.js";
import { React, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Button, Col, Container, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch , useSelector } from "react-redux";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import imgIcon from "./img/programmer.png";
import style from "../styles/RegisterUser.module.css";
import NavBarRegisters from "./NavBarRegisters.jsx";

function RegisterUser() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const history = useHistory();
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

const [input, setInput] = useState({
email: "",
password: "",
confirmPassword: "",
name: "",
lastname: "",
birthDate: "",
});

function handleChange(e) {
setInput({
  ...input,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
});
setErrors(
  validateUsers({
    ...input,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.name,
  })
);
}
function handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (input.password !== input.confirmPassword) {
  swal(
    "Las contraseñas no coinciden",
    "Por favor vuelva a ingresar su contraseña",
    "error"
  );
  return;
}
if (
  input.email !== "" &&
  input.password !== "" &&
  input.password === input.confirmPassword &&
  input.password.length >= 8 &&
  input.password.length <= 16 &&
  input.confirmPassword.length >= 8 &&
  input.confirmPassword.length <= 16 &&
  input.name !== "" &&
  input.lastname !== "" &&
  input.birthDate !== ""
) {
  dispatch(addUser(input));
  
} else {
  swal(
    "Faltan datos por llenar",
    "Por favor ingrese todos los datos",
    "error"
  );
}
}

const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
if (didMount) {
  setDidMount(false);
  return; 
} else {
  if ( user === "Usuario creado") {
  swal("Buen trabajo!", "El usuario fue creado con exito!", "success");
  setInput({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    name: "",
    lastname: "",
    birthDate: "",
  });
  history.push("/persona");
  } else if ( user === "error:Validation error") {
  swal("Ya existe un usuario con el email");
  dispatch(cleanUsers());
  }
 }
 }, [user]);


return (
<div className={style.divContainer}>
  <NavBarRegisters />
  <div className={style.divContainerForms}>
    <Container>
      <h1 className="shadow-sm text-success mt-5 p-3 text-center rounded">
        Registrar Usuario
      </h1>
      <Row>
        <Col
          lg={8}
          md={6}
          sm={12}
          className="text-center p-5 m-auto shadow-sm rounded-lg"
        >
          <img className="iconImg" src={imgIcon} alt="icon" />
          <Form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} className={style.forms}>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                placeholder="Enter email"
            
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Fecha nacimiento</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="date"
                placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento"
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                value={input.birthDate}
                name="birthDate"
                id="birthDate"
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button
              variant="primary"
              className="mt-3 mb-5 w-100 mt-3"
              type="submit"
            >
              REGISTRARME
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <h6 className="mt-5 p-5 text-center text-secondary ">
        © 2022 Bring it. All Rights Reserved | Design by Grupo 8 Soy Henry
      </h6>
    </Container>
  </div>
</div>
);
}

export default RegisterUser;
```

Comment: This is an algorithm question moreso than it is a react question. Look into the `Date` object or check out moment.js

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that calculates it or easier to use a library like `Moment.js` or `Datefns`
The function for calculating days - the psuedo code/algo could be sth from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091965/18821127

```
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```