# Random photos from Flickr JSON feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use this query to parse a JSON feed from a flickr account and inject the code of the latest 12 photos from that feed in a div named #photos

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                // Set variables needed for query
                var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
                var ID = "<?php echo get_option('of_flickrid') ?>";
                var jsonFormat = "&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

                var ajaxURL = URL + "?id=" + ID + jsonFormat;
                // Get the last photos of the flickr account, parse it into HTML code
                $.getJSON(ajaxURL, function(data){
                     var htmlString = '<a href="<?php echo get_option('of_flickr') ?>" target="_blank"><h1><?php echo get_option('of_photostext') ?></h1></a><br class="clear"/>';

                    // Now start cycling through our array of Flickr photo details
                    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){

                        // I only want the ickle square thumbnails
                     var sourceSquare = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_s.jpg");

                        // Here's where we piece together the HTML
                        htmlString += '<a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank">';
                        htmlString += '<img title="' + item.title + '" src="' + sourceSquare;
                        htmlString += '" alt="'; htmlString += item.title + '" class="rounded"/>';
                        htmlString += '</a>';
                        if(i === 11){
                            return false;
                        }
                    });             

                    // Pop our HTML in the #images DIV
                    $('#photos').html(htmlString);

                }); // End getJSOON
</script>
```

but I need to load 12 random photos rather than the latest 12, how can I do this?

Comment: i think flicker API dose not support such feature and you have to do it on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump them all into an array, then splice out [elements at random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-array-with-jquery). Since [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) actually removes elements from the original array, you won't have to worry about extracting the same item twice.

```
$.getJSON(ajaxURL, function(data){
   var items = data.items, // array
       extract = [], // array
       max = 12; // number of items to remove
   for (var i=0; i<max; i++) {
     var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length); // a random index
     extract.push(items.splice(rand,1)[0]); // splice() returns an array
   };
   // do something with 'extract'
});
```