# jQuery, Generate random main category on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, random

I'm having an (beginner)issue where I want to generate a random, in this example, `Gender` that'll decide from what array the name is picked. This works fine if i run the code with a fixed variable like `var Gender = 'boy'`, but when I try to make this step I'm far from successful. The goal is to randomize a gender each time the Randomize button is clicked and get a name from the corresponding array.

After having looked at examples like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-array-with-jquery), and still not being able to solve my problem I'm starting to wonder what I'm failing so miserably at. I do understand that maybe this shouldn't really be a new question here on Stackoverflow since it's so basic, but I *really* do appreciate any help I get with this one.

[jsFiddle of my (nonworking) code](http://jsfiddle.net/lennyekberg/hweUw/)

```
//var Gender = 'boy' /*for testing*/

var GenderSelection = [
    'boy',
    'girl'
    ];

    var Gender = Math.floor(Math.random()*GenderSelection.length);

    /* previous, broken code
    maxGenderSelection = GenderSelection.length;
    var Gender = Math.floor(Math.random()*(GenderSelection.length));
    */

if(Gender == 'boy') {
/////////////////////////////
//   Foretagsnamn (Name)   //
/////////////////////////////
    var Foretagsnamn = [
    'Matt',
    'Carl',
    'Ron'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxForetagsnamn = Foretagsnamn.length;

// get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomForetagsnamn() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxForetagsnamn = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxForetagsnamn));
    //return the random sentence
    return Foretagsnamn[rndIdxForetagsnamn];                        
}

var randomName = getRandomForetagsnamn();

//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
function showRandomForetagsnamn(selector){
  var randomForetagsnamn = getRandomForetagsnamn(); 
  randomName = randomForetagsnamn;  
  $(selector).html(randomForetagsnamn);
}
}

if(Gender == 'girl') {
/////////////////////////////
//   Foretagsnamn (Name)   //
/////////////////////////////
    var Foretagsnamn = [
    'Lisa',
    'Ann',
    'Sara'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxForetagsnamn = Foretagsnamn.length;

// get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomForetagsnamn() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxForetagsnamn = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxForetagsnamn));
    //return the random sentence
    return Foretagsnamn[rndIdxForetagsnamn];                        
}

var randomName = getRandomForetagsnamn();

//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
function showRandomForetagsnamn(selector){
  var randomForetagsnamn = getRandomForetagsnamn(); 
  randomName = randomForetagsnamn;  
  $(selector).html(randomForetagsnamn);
}
}

else {
    // code to be executed if condition is false
    alert('No soup for you!');
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   Foretagsbeskrivning (Workdescription)   //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////


var Foretagsbeskrivning = [
    'is an ice cream vendor',
    'is a telemarketer',
    'builds hybrid cars'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxForetagsbeskrivning = Foretagsbeskrivning.length;  

//get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomForetagsbeskrivning() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxForetagsbeskrivning = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxForetagsbeskrivning));
    //return the random sentence
    return Foretagsbeskrivning[rndIdxForetagsbeskrivning];                        
}


//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
    //vad är en DOM selector, för alla taggar i html eller?
function showRandomForetagsbeskrivning(selector){
  var randomForetagsbeskrivning = getRandomForetagsbeskrivning();  
  $(selector).html(randomForetagsbeskrivning);
}


////////////////////////////
//   Målsättning (Goal)   //
////////////////////////////


var Malsattning = [
    '@@person@@ wants to serve a combination of cooling flavours', // aimed at ice cream vendor
    'The long term goal is for @@person@@ to buy ', // aimed at ice cream vendor
    'The vision is for @@person@@ to be the most productive salesperson in the office', // aimed at telemarketer
    'The vision is for @@person@@ to call more than 5000 customers this week', // aimed at telemarketer
    'The goal for @@person@@ is to develop a car that can travel in the speed of light', // aimed at car builder
    '@@person@@ wants to create a vehicle capable of being powered by water' // aimed at car builder
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxMalsattning = Malsattning.length;  

//get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomMalsattning() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxMalsattning = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxMalsattning));
    //return the random sentence
    return Malsattning[rndIdxMalsattning];                        
}


//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
    //vad är en DOM selector, för alla taggar i html eller?
function showRandomMalsattning(selector){
  var randomMalsattning = getRandomMalsattning();  
  $(selector).html(randomMalsattning.replace('@@person@@', randomName));

}





//////////////////
//    Output    //
//////////////////


//used to output the different sentences
//used by .click & .ready beneath
var outputLista = function() {
    showRandomForetagsnamn(".foretagsnamn");
    showRandomForetagsbeskrivning(".foretagsbeskrivning");
    showRandomMalsattning(".malsattning");
   }


$('.rndButton').click(function(e){
    outputLista();
    console.log('get random sentences at click...');
});

//generates random sentences when the page loads
$('.rndButton').ready(function(e){
    console.log('get random sentences at page load...');
    outputLista();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

your code was so much redundant. I think that is what you wanted to achieve.

```
var GenderSelection = [ 'boy', 'girl' ],
    Foretagsnamn = [],       
    randomName = "",
    Foretagsbeskrivning = [
    'is an ice cream vendor',
    'is a telemarketer',
    'builds hybrid cars'
    ],    
    maxForetagsbeskrivning = Foretagsbeskrivning.length,
    Malsattning = [
    '@@person@@ wants to serve a combination of cooling flavours', // aimed at ice cream vendor
    'The long term goal is for @@person@@ to buy ', // aimed at ice cream vendor
    'The vision is for @@person@@ to be the most productive salesperson in the office', // aimed at telemarketer
    'The vision is for @@person@@ to call more than 5000 customers this week', // aimed at telemarketer
    'The goal for @@person@@ is to develop a car that can travel in the speed of light', // aimed at car builder
    '@@person@@ wants to create a vehicle capable of being powered by water' // aimed at car builder
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxMalsattning = Malsattning.length; 

function onRandomize(){

var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*GenderSelection.length),
    Gender = GenderSelection[index],
    workDescription = getRandomWorkDescription(),
    goal = getRandomMalsattning();

    Foretagsnamn = [ 'Matt', 'Carl', 'Ron'];                  
    if(Gender == 'girl') {
        Foretagsnamn = [ 'Lisa', 'Ann', 'Sara' ];
    }

   randomName = getRandomForetagsnamn()
   $(".foretagsnamn").text(randomName);
   $(".foretagsbeskrivning").text(workDescription);   
   var replaceName =  goal.replace("@@person@@",randomName);       
   $(".malsattning").text(replaceName);
}

// get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomForetagsnamn() {   
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*(Foretagsnamn.length));    
    return Foretagsnamn[index];
}

function getRandomWorkDescription(){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxForetagsbeskrivning)); 
    return Foretagsbeskrivning[index];
}

function getRandomMalsattning() {    
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxMalsattning));    
    return Malsattning[index];                        
}

onRandomize();

$('.rndButton').click(function(e){
    onRandomize();
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hweUw/8/

i hope it helps.

Comment: Redundant indeed. Your version seem to accomplish what I'm after, one thing I don't get though is the second declaration of `Foretagsnamn = [ 'Matt', 'Carl', 'Ron'],` – Whats the point of declaring the three of the male names there? (Also, wouldn't it be easier to have the names in only one place?

Comment: @Lenny:: That is why because if the array is filled with girls name and let say gender comes male then what would happen?? it will choose from girls name. thats why i just again filled array with respective girls and boys names..

Comment: ah, I worded my question a bit unclear; what I meant was on the second line `Matt, Carl, Ron` are declared as Foretagsnamn while no mention of the female names. Is this just so that the array is of the correct length later on or something?

Comment: yes you are saying right. I just updated code above you can also do that way too.