# Random images with just 3 images in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make a function `RandomSwapDown(x)` randomly so that it shows one of the three images every time you click on it?
Thank you.

```
<script>
    function RandomSwapDown(x) {                 
        x.src = '4.gif';    
    }                               
    function SwapBack(x) {       
        x.src = 'mouse_over.png';           
    }
    function SwapOut(x) {
        x.src = 'mouse_normal.png';
    }  
</script>

</html>

<div style='top: 200px; left: 175px; position: absolute;'>

<img src='mouse_normal.png'  onMouseOver='SwapBack(this)' onMouseOut= 'SwapOut(this)' onMouseDown = 'RandomSwapDown(this)' width="121" height="146" >

<img src='mouse_normal.png'  onMouseOver='SwapBack(this)' onMouseOut= 'SwapOut(this)' onMouseDown = 'RandomSwapDown(this)' width="121" height="146" >

<img src='mouse_normal.png'  onMouseOver='SwapBack(this)' onMouseOut= 'SwapOut(this)' onMouseDown = 'RandomSwapDown(this)' width="121" height="146" >

</div>
```

Comment: This isn't random at all....

Comment: You can generate random numbers with the Math.random() function.

Comment: I think this deserves a link and run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/Q5me6/1/)

```
var picArr = []; // array of images to choose from

function RandomSwapDown(x) {
    x.src = picArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
function SwapBack(x) {
    x.src = picArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
function SwapOut(x) {
    x.src = picArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i don't now you can use this in javascript but in java you can

```
Random generator=new Random();    
int rnd_number;    
rnd_number=generator.nextInt(MaxRandom-MinRandom)+MinRandom;
```