# How to grab a li and append it randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a website where you put your names into an input, and press "calculate" and it will take a random li with that name and append it to a box. This is my HTML:

```
<form class="newName">
            <label for="nameInput">Your Name</label>
            <input class="input-md" id="nameInput" placeholder="(e.g: John Smith)">
            <span class="btn-names">Enter...</span>
            <span class="calculate">Calculate</span>
        </form>
        <div class="namesEntered">
            <ul id="enteredNames"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="centered">
            <h1>And The Winner Is....</h1><br><br>
            <span id="name" class="names">???</span>
        </div>
```

And my JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-names').on('click', function(){
        if ($('#nameInput').val() === ''){
        alert('No names have been entered');
    } else {
        var $inputted_names = $('#nameInput').val();
        var listed = '<li>'+ $inputted_names +'</li>';
        $(listed).appendTo('ul');
        $('#nameInput').val('');
    }
    });
    $('.calculate').on('click', function(){
        var tag = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var name = tag.innerHTML;
        var randomator = Math.floor(Math.random(tag) * name.length);
        console.log(randomator);
    });
});
```

You can view this example website at http://www.b3ws.com/randomator.html
But it doesn't work just yet

Comment: Great, Let us know when it's ready!

Comment: @Andrew It's ready :D Right now I have to code it for a keydown event, but right now it's working thanks to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get an array of `li` elements like

```
var names = $('#enteredNames li');
```

Then, get the random name

```
var randomName = names.get(Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length));
```

Finally, change the `#name` span

```
$('#name').text(randomName.innerHTML);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-names').on('click', function(){
        if ($('#nameInput').val() === ''){
        alert('No names have been entered');
    } else {
        var $inputted_names = $('#nameInput').val();
        var listed = '<li>'+ $inputted_names +'</li>';
        $(listed).appendTo('ul');
        $('#nameInput').val('');
    }
    });
    $('.calculate').on('click', function(){
        var names = $('#enteredNames li');
        var randomName = names.get(Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length));
        $('#name').text(randomName.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="nameInput">Your Name</label>
            <input class="input-md" id="nameInput" placeholder="(e.g: John Smith)">
            <span class="btn-names">Enter...</span>
            <span class="calculate">Calculate</span>
        
        <div class="namesEntered">
            <ul id="enteredNames"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="centered">
            <h1>And The Winner Is....</h1><br><br>
            <span id="name" class="names">???</span>
        </div>
```

Also, see [Get random item from JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace your randomator section with this:

var randomator = Math.floor(Math.random() * tag.length); //don't need tag in random function
console.log(randomator);
$('.names').html(tag[randomator].text()); //assign the test from the random tag to the element with the names class
```