# Randomly assigning an object prop from a file to inline-css

Tags: javascript, css, json, node.js, reactjs

I have a file let's say Colors.js which contains some hex values as follows:

```
module.exports = {

  red50:    '#ffebee',
  red100:   '#ffcdd2',
  red200:   '#ef9a9a',
  red300:   '#e57373',
  red400:   '#ef5350',
  red500:   '#f44336',
  red600:   '#e53935',
  red700:   '#d32f2f',
  red800:   '#c62828',
  red900:   '#b71c1c'

};
```

What I'm trying in another file is is to randomly take the above-defined objects and assign them as `inline-css` `backgroundColor` after importing Colors.js file

So eventually instead of defining one of them manually as follows:

```
import Colors from "../Colors";
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        someStyle: {
            background: Colors.red500
        },
    };
};
```

I can return a random Color object

```
import Colors from "../UI/Colors";
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        someStyle: {
            background: `Randomly picked object from Color.js file`
        },
    };
};
```

I'm pretty much clueless on how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array

Comment: Is your question on how to get a random color or assigning it to the prop?

Comment: @BradBumbalough: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question description. I would like to take a random color from Colors.js and assigning it to the background prop.

Answer (score 0):

This is very Easy...

Use Math.random() function of javascript to get a random Value and add that

say background: funtion(){return module.exports[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);]

this will return any random value between 1 to 10 as an index. 
make exports an array and pull that value using this random index 
and then finally return that value.

Answer (score 0):

try this.create a hex random number and return it as background color.i hope you  do not want it to be fetched from your file.
**Edit**:check the logic.not sure about syntax

```
import Colors from "../Colors";
    module.exports = function() {
                      var num=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                      var color='red'+num;
        return {
            someStyle: {

                         background: colors[color];
            },
        };
    };
```

Comment: well, I would like to get only the predefined colors from Colors.js file

Comment: Doesn't work. The styles are not applied to the element.
let num=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
someStyle: {
background: Colors[num];
},

Comment: check the code.it is not Colors[num].it is **Colors[color]**

Comment: oh well, I am using the first variable. I don't need to append `red` prefix.