# Add class to random li in all ul's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, survey

```
<div id="question-1" name="question" 
    <ul>  
        <li name="347815" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548094" value="7548094">1</li>
        <li name="347815" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548095" value="7548095">2</li>
        <li name="347815" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548096" value="7548096">3</li>
        <li name="347815" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548097" value="7548097">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="question-2" name="question" 
    <ul> 
        <li name="347818" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548140" value="7548140">1</li>
        <li name="347818" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548143" value="7548143">2</li>
        <li name="347818" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548168" value="7548168">Hemköp</li>
        <li name="347818" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548169" value="7548169">3</li>
        <li name="347818" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548184" value="7548184">4</li>
        <li name="347818" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548195" value="7548195">5</li>
        <li name="347818" class="MULTIPLE" id="7548208" value="7548208">6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need a js "jquery" code to select a random li element from all ul lists. The list number changes constantly so I need to use something like .find();

This is the code that I have right no but it doesn't select one li in all ul, it selects random li in random ul:

```
var list = $('ul > li');
list.eq(parseInt(Math.random()*list.length)).addClass('selected');
```

Thank you guys :)

**UPDATE:**

@MTCoster has the right answer, here is it:

`$("ul").each(function() {
  var liArr = $(this).children("li");
  $(liArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * liArr.length)]).addClass('selected');
});`

Comment: Arithmetic functions return numbers, you don't have to call `parseInt()` on them.

Comment: The `parseInt()` is being used here in place of `Math.floor()` as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array) question on randomly selecting array elements in JavaScript.

Comment: @MTCoster OK, it will work, but it's definitely a confusing way to do it.

Comment: It's also unnecessary. `.eq()` will convert its argument to an integer automatically.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to select the same random LI in each UL? If so you could just filter on nth-child instead of using `eq`, something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/04b0ju4h/2/

Comment: @HassanIla Is requirement a) to select different random `li` in each `ul` ? , or b) select random number , select `li` at index of random number from each `ul` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have at the moment is creating a single array of all `li` elements that exist within a `ul` element, then selecting one of them.  What you need to do is select all the `ul` elements first, then select a random `li` element from *each one*.  Try something like this:

```
$("ul").each(function() {
  var liArr = $(this).children("li");
  $(liArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * liArr.length)]).addClass('selected');
});
```

**Edit:** you have to wrap the selected element from the array in a jQuery selector; I've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry but it says Uncaught TypeError: liArr[Math.floor(...)].addClass is not a function.. Otherwise this is exactly what I want.

Comment: This is what I need but can someone please fix it so I don't get: Uncaught TypeError: liArr[Math.floor(...)].addClass is not a function..   I will mark it as resolved then.... Thank you

Comment: @HassanIla This error is thrown because you're trying to call a jQuery method on a non-jQuery object.  The fix is as simple as wrapping the array element in a jQuery selector.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you so much I've made it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.each()`

```
   // select all `ul` elements
   $("ul").each(function() {
      // select all `li` elements that are children of `this` `ul`
      var list = $("> li", this);
      list.eq(Math.random() * list.length).addClass("selected");
   })
```

Comment: And to check : more .addClass("selected").prop("checked",true); ;)