# JavaScript - Output random OBJECT from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, random

Quick question, I have an array of objects:

```
var objects = [
  {username: jon, count: 5},
  {username: sally, count: 7},
  {username: mark, count: 9,
]
```

I want to output one of these objects at random so that I can access its properties and not just it's index.
How do I do this?

Comment: Your answer already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 1):

First calculate a random index:

```
var random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
//                                            ^ Length of array
```

then access the object with that index:

```
var obj = objects[random_index];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomObject = objects[Math.floor(Math.random() * objects.length)];
```

Explanation: `Math.random()` gets you a value between 0 and 1, multiply that by `objects.length` to get a number between 0 and `objects.length`, and use `Math.floor()` to truncate the decimal portion. Return the value at that position of `objects`.