# Run functions randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that includes some functions and it looks like this:

```
var all_questions = [
    show_question(1, 1),
    show_question(2, 1),
    show_question(3, 1),
];
```

I would like to run those functions into that array randomly. How can I do that?

Comment: All functions will be executed at the time when the array is getting created

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: To extend @RajaprabhuAravindasamy's comment - the parenthesis at the end of the function name is what actually "calls" the function.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "run those functions into that array randomly". Do you mean you want to run only one of them? Or run them all in a random order? Or something else?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you need to wrap those functions in anonymous functions, otherwise they will be called immediately. From there you can [get a random element from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5915096/519413) and call it, like this:

```js
var all_questions = [
    function() { show_question(1, 1) },
    function() { show_question(2, 1) },
    function() { show_question(3, 1) },
];

all_questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * all_questions.length)]();

function show_question(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
}
```

Note that you could improve the logic by just randomising the first parameter of the function only, instead of storing function references in an array:

```js
function show_question(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
}

var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
show_question(rnd, 1);
```

Comment: It's most likely for posting an answer on a very poorly written question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling the same function with different arguments, I would say it's a better option to select the arguments randomly instead of the function.

```
var args = [
  [1,2],
  [1,3],
  [1,4],
  ...
]

// Get a random element from the array
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/4550514/558021
var randomArgs = args[ Math.floor( Math.random()*args.length) ];

show_question.apply( this, randomArgs );
```

The [apply function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is used here because of the way it passes arguments to the target function. When you use `apply` to execute a function, the arguments you want to pass to the function are provided in an array and then split into individual arguments when passed to the target function.

Comment: You could use `show_question.apply(randomArgs)` and the OP wouldn't need to amend the function at all.

Comment: I considered that but in the end chose this approach as I felt it would better suite the competence level of this question.

Comment: I can understand that, although IMO it's better to bring someone up to your level instead of catering to theirs.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
var all_questions = [
    function() show_question(1, 1),
    function() show_question(2, 1),
    function() show_question(3, 1),
];
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
// do something you want
    all_questions[x];
```

Comment: Just like in the original question, the functions will be called while you are defining the array.

Comment: @liam - did you notice that you removed a portion of the code sample that was provided?

Comment: hmm, not on purpose @lix. Edited to do what I actually meant to do, appologies

Comment: @liam - no worries, just wanted to give you a heads up

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this;

```
var allQuestions = [
                    showQuestion.bind(this, 1, 1),
                    showQuestion.bind(this, 2, 1),
                    showQuestion.bind(this, 3, 1),
                   ],
 displayQuestion = allQuestions[~~(Math.random()*allQuestions.length)];
```