# random letter blinking effect [with diff font colors]

Tags: javascript, html, colors

Okay, so I'm in the process of making a web page for myself/for fun and I wanted the title on the web page to have like a blinking effect. like, think of a light bulb and its flickering, but I wanted random letters to flicker as well. I know this might involve some java script and I'm not that great with it yet and I couldn't find examples so I thought I'd try this place out and see if someone can help me?
so, I'm using inspiration from a cartoon here's the link: https://youtu.be/No_omXE6TK0?t=14s
I kinda wanted it to look like that with the flickering. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not sure that it is possible to change the color of `title` element, though should be possible to change text of rendered `title` text content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of you can't run the snippet, here is the fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/8m667mj4/`

```js
var string = x.innerHTML;
var aBlinkingString = "";
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    aBlinkingString += "<span class='blink'>" + string[i] + "</span>";
}
x.innerHTML = aBlinkingString;
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
setInterval(function() {
            document.querySelectorAll(".blink")[Math.round((document.querySelectorAll(".blink").length - 1) * Math.random())].style.color = colors[Math.round((colors.length - 1) * Math.random())];
            }, 10)
```

```html
<h1 id="x">
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
</h1>
```

I set the `h1` element's `id` to `x` so I can access it in DOM later.

In the `for` loop, I wrap every letter in the `h1` element in a `span` element.

Then, I access a random `span` element and change its color randomly.

See this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array` to know how to pick random element from array and `http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp` to know how to set color of an element.

Comment: oh my gosh thank you so much! this is gonna help me so much omg you're a life saver!! :D

Comment: @nivi Give me link to your website when you finished that :D

Comment: well im using it on tumblr for now but sure!! :D

Comment: also, did it not check? i hope it checked it ;w;

Comment: it checked now.